# how can i make high quality image icon in java swing?

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, image-resizing, imageicon

I am working with a java [swing](/questions/tagged/swing) application project. I want to make an image as icon in my `JPanel` but it seems to be low quality image when i am printing the image using the external printer. Here is the code

```
    ImageIcon ii=new ImageIcon(scaleImage(90, 107, ImageIO.read(new File(f.getAbsolutePath()))));
    image.setIcon(ii);
```

How can I make high quality image icon other than this method?

Comment: Read about image resizing (i.e. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14115950/quality-of-image-after-resize-very-low-java ). Also consider sending ready image in correct size without resizing it inside the application.

Comment: SCALE_SMOOTH method may be helpful to you.
[Image.SCALE_SMOOTH](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Image.html#SCALE_SMOOTH)

Answer (score 0):

If you use a downscaled version of an image for an `Icon`, the resolution loss cannot be compensated when printing the icon.

Instead of using `ImageIcon`, you can create your own icon class (by implementing the `javax.swing.Icon` interface, it's actually quite simple), which keeps your Image at a higher resolution and paints it at a smaller size (but without quality loss, so you still can see more detail when printing it).
This can be done by applying an `AffineTransform`/Scale prior to drawing the Image, or by using `graphics.drawImage(x,y,width,height,imageObserver)`.