# Resize/compress picture using Apache POI hslf - PowerPoint

Tags: java, apache-poi, powerpoint

Hi I build a powerpoint presentation using apache poi and add a lot of images to the presentation.

```
private void addImage(SlideShow slideShow, Sheet slide, File image, int x, int y, int w, int h) {
    try {
        int idx = slideShow.addPicture(image, Picture.JPEG);
        Picture pict = new Picture(idx);
        pict.setAnchor(new Rectangle(x, y, w, h));
        slide.addShape(pict);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The function works and I get a ppt presentation in the end, but the ppt file is too big and at another PC I get a heap space error.
So I would like to resize / compress my images in the slides. I have four pictures on each slide - so they don't need to have the original resolution.

Is there a build in function in poi to do this?
Something like

```
pict.resize(width, height);
```

I'm using apache poi 3.7

thx in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

POI doesn't modify the pictureData itself. You'll need to [resample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14115950) it yourself before.

Comment: Hi Kiwiwings ok - now I convert the images on my own. I thought maybe there is a way to use the PowerPoint way function like here

http://www.wikihow.com/Reduce-Powerpoint-File-Size

"Choose E-mail (96 ppi) output to reduce the size of PowerPoint.Picture Tools >>Format >> Compress Pictures >> Options >> Target Output >> E-mail (96 ppi)"

Comment: ... might be a nice idea for an extension. It's easy to iterate through all the pictures of the slides and find out their dimensions and calculate the pixel width/height for the given ppis. Maybe you could file a enhancement entry in the poi-bugzilla ...