# How to set imageicon fix on jlabel

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to make a java desktop application. I have a `JLabel` where I am shuffling image but all image sizes are different so I want to fix size of the image on `JLabel`.

How can I do this?

Here is my code :

```
public class ImageShuffle1 extends JPanel {

   private List<Icon> list = new ArrayList<Icon>();
   private List<Icon> shuffled;
   private JLabel label = new JLabel();
   private Timer timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {

      @Override
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        update();
       }
   });

   public ImageShuffle1() {
       this.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 0));

      list.add(new ImageIcon("E:\\SOFTWARE\\TrainPIS\\res\\drawable\\e.jpg"));
    list.add(new ImageIcon("E:\\SOFTWARE\\TrainPIS\\res\\drawable\\d.jpg"));
    list.add(new ImageIcon("E:\\SOFTWARE\\TrainPIS\\res\\drawable\\yellow.png"));
      list.add(new ImageIcon("E:\\SOFTWARE\\TrainPIS\\res\\drawable\\f.jpg"));
            list.add(new ImageIcon("E:\\SOFTWARE\\TrainPIS\\res\\drawable\\l.jpg"));
       //label.setIcon(UIManager.getIcon("OptionPane.informationIcon"));

    for(Icon icon: list){

       Image img = icon.getImage() ;

       // put here the size properties  
       Image newimg = img.getScaledInstance( 45, 34,  java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH ) ;  

       icon = new ImageIcon(newimg);

    }

shuffled = new ArrayList<Icon>(list);
Collections.shuffle(shuffled);
       timer.start();
   }

   private void update() {
      if (shuffled.isEmpty()) {
    shuffled = new ArrayList<Icon>(list);
    Collections.shuffle(shuffled);
 }

 Icon icon = shuffled.remove(0);
 label.setIcon(icon);
}

private void display() {
    JFrame f = new JFrame("ImageShuffle");
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.add(this);
    f.add(label);
    f.pack();
    f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    f.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

           @Override
          public void run() {
              new ImageShuffle1().display();
           }
       });
   }
 }
```

I am getting error herein this.

> line/variable getimage can not found mage img = icon.getImage() ;

Thanks in advance

Comment: You already asked this question and got answers yesterday. Quit cluttering the forum with duplicate questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Use BufferedImage in place of Icon that has a functionality to re size it.

Here is the code

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class ImageShuffle1 extends JPanel {

    private List<BufferedImage> list = new ArrayList<BufferedImage>();
    private List<BufferedImage> shuffled;
    private JLabel label = new JLabel();

    private int width = 50;
    private int height = 100;

    private Timer timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            update();
        }
    });

    public ImageShuffle1() {

        try {
            list.add(resizeImage(ImageIO.read(new File("resources/1.png"))));
            list.add(resizeImage(ImageIO.read(new File("resources/2.png"))));
            list.add(resizeImage(ImageIO.read(new File("resources/6.png"))));
            list.add(resizeImage(ImageIO.read(new File("resources/Tulips.jpg"))));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        shuffled = new ArrayList<BufferedImage>(list);
        Collections.shuffle(shuffled);
        timer.start();
    }

    private BufferedImage resizeImage(BufferedImage originalImage) throws IOException {
        BufferedImage resizedImage = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics2D g = resizedImage.createGraphics();
        g.drawImage(originalImage, 0, 0, width, height, null);
        g.dispose();
        return resizedImage;
    }

    private void update() {
        if (shuffled.isEmpty()) {
            shuffled = new ArrayList<BufferedImage>(list);
            Collections.shuffle(shuffled);
        }

        BufferedImage icon = shuffled.remove(0);
        label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(icon));
    }

    private void display() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("ImageShuffle");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add(this);
        f.add(label);
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new ImageShuffle1().display();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: how to retrieve image from  project  folder

Comment: Try this one `ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("3.png")))` to read image file from the same package where class is present.

Comment: i dont want only single image i want all image

Comment: Is there any problem in calling this more than one time with different image file name?

Comment: i am not getting properly how to do this

Comment: Are you talking about images stored at `"E:\\SOFTWARE\\TrainPIS\\res\\drawable\\` location. Is it your project folder? or an absolute location outside project.

Comment: this  is the location oustside the folder

Comment: You have to read about, how to read a file from an absolute location. Use this one `new File("E:\\SOFTWARE\\TrainPIS\\res\\drawable\\e.jpg")`.

Answer (score 1):

Lets start with this...

```
for(Icon icon: list){

   Image img = icon.getImage() ;
```

`Icon` does not have a method `getImage`, there is actually no way to get the "image" data maintained by the `Icon` class without first rendering it to something (like a `BufferedImage`)

A better solution might be to load the images into a `List` that supports `BufferedImage`.  `BufferedImage` is a more versatile starting point and because it extends from `Image`, it can be used with `ImageIcon`.  For example...

```
private List<BufferedImage> list = new ArrayList<BufferedImage>();
//...
list.add(ImageIO.read("E:\\SOFTWARE\\TrainPIS\\res\\drawable\\e.jpg"));
```

Take a look at [Reading/Loading an Image](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html)

For scaling you might like to take a look at

- [The Perils of Image.getScaledInstance](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/04/03/perils-of-image-getscaledinstance.html)
- [Java: maintaining aspect ratio of JPanel background image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11959758/java-maintaining-aspect-ratio-of-jpanel-background-image/11959928#11959928)
- [Quality of Image after resize very low -- Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14115950/quality-of-image-after-resize-very-low-java/14116752#14116752)

Answer (score 0):

First you resize every image to a fixed size and it must be fit in `JLabel`

```
public static Boolean resizeImage(String sourceImage, String destinationImage, Integer   Width, Integer Height) {
    BufferedImage origImage;
    try {

        origImage = ImageIO.read(new File(sourceImage));
        int type = origImage.getType() == 0? BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB :  origImage.getType();

        //*Special* if the width or height is 0 use image src dimensions
        if (Width == 0) {
            Width = origImage.getWidth();
        }
        if (Height == 0) {
            Height = origImage.getHeight();
        }

        int fHeight = Height;
        int fWidth = Width;

        //Work out the resized width/height
        if (origImage.getHeight() > Height || origImage.getWidth() > Width) {
            fHeight = Height;
            int wid = Width;
            float sum = (float)origImage.getWidth() / (float)origImage.getHeight();
            fWidth = Math.round(fHeight * sum);

            if (fWidth > wid) {
                //rezise again for the width this time
                fHeight = Math.round(wid/sum);
                fWidth = wid;
            }
        }

        BufferedImage resizedImage = new BufferedImage(fWidth, fHeight, type);
        Graphics2D g = resizedImage.createGraphics();
        g.setComposite(AlphaComposite.Src);

        g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION,  RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
        g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
        g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        g.drawImage(origImage, 0, 0, fWidth, fHeight, null);
        g.dispose();

        ImageIO.write(resizedImage, "png", new File(destinationImage));
        ...
```

Comment: can u tell me where i will have to make change  in my code

Comment: you must resize every image beofore adding it to ArrayList .Then add the paths of resized images into list.Thats all.

Comment: Please learn and use [Code Conventions for the Java Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html)

Comment: Using `drawImage` for scaling is not a highly recommended scaling solution, there are better options

Comment: @MadProgrammer Download link redirected to a error page.