# Java GUI Resize Images

Tags: java, image, swing, user-interface, resize

I would like to resize multiple imageIcons that I have attached to certain panels, but I'm not sure how to do that. After much research I've attempted to use .getScaledInstance but have had no luck, is that what I'm supposed to use? Since I define my panels outside of the main class but need to use the scaled instances of the images in multiple methods, would I add a line such as

```
image.getImage().getScaledInstance(30,30,whatever);
```

or would I need to do a different action?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`getScaledInstance` doesn't effect the original image, but instead returns a new instance of the image scaled to meet your parameters, make sure you are assigning the result to a variable, for example

```
image = image.getImage().getScaledInstance(30,30,whatever);
```

Then pass this to your what ever needs to use it

Beware, the quality of the operation is pretty poor, especially over a large range.

Take a look at

- [Quality of Image after resize very low -- Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14115950/quality-of-image-after-resize-very-low-java/14116752#14116752)
- [Java: maintaining aspect ratio of JPanel background image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11959758/java-maintaining-aspect-ratio-of-jpanel-background-image/11959928#11959928)
- [The Perils of Image.getScaledInstance()](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/04/03/perils-of-image-getscaledinstance.html)

For details and ideas.

Comment: Is getScaledInstance the only way to resize an image? If it's of a poor quality what's a higher quality version

Comment: Check the linked examples.  The first one offers a slightly different approach (multi stage downsizing). You could also consider having a look at [imgscalr](http://www.thebuzzmedia.com/software/imgscalr-java-image-scaling-library/)