# Java Image not scaling

Tags: java, graphics, awt, bufferedimage

Not sure what I am doing wrong, but the image that is saved is the same as the original ~ 500px high. I am trying to set the image to 100px high and keep the aspectratio the same. Then save the smaller version.

```
BufferedImage original = ImageIO.read(inputStream);
Integer width = original.getWidth();
float aspectratio = (float)original.getWidth()/(float)original.getHeight();
Integer newwidth= Math.round(100*aspectratio);
BufferedImage scaledImage = new BufferedImage(newwidth,100,original.getType());
Graphics2D g = scaledImage.createGraphics();
g.drawImage(scaledImage,0,0,null);
g.dispose();
ImageIO.write(scaledImage, "PNG", result);
```

Comment: You might Ike to consider having a look at [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11959758/java-maintaining-aspect-ratio-of-jpanel-background-image/11959928#11959928) and [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14115950/quality-of-image-after-resize-very-low-java/14116752#14116752) for some pointers on scaling images

Comment: Not the downvoter, but I would "guess" that the answer to your problem could be easily researched by googling, searching SO or reading the JavaDocs...at a "guess"

Comment: As you create `scaledImage` with explicit height `100`, there's no chance that the resulting image will be anything but 100 pixels tall. However, there's an obvious typo in your code, `g.drawImage(scaledImage,0,0,null)` draws `scaledImage` onto itself...  So what you should have is a completely transparent or black image with the correct size. Unless there's something you've left out. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `drawImage(Image, int, int, ImageObserver)` doesn't scale the image. Also, you are drawing the image to itself. You need to use the overload of `drawImage` that scales the image, like this:

```
// ...
Graphics2D g = scaledImage.createGraphics();
g.drawImage(original, 0, 0, scaledImage.getWidth(), scaledImage.getHeight(), 0, 0, original.getWidth(), original.getHeight(), null);
// ...
```

See more info on the [JavaDocs for `Graphics`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawImage%28java.awt.Image,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20java.awt.image.ImageObserver%29).

Comment: FYI although the OPs code will handle this, beware that this version of drawImage will stretch the image to meet the requirements of the destination width/height, without consideration of original images aspect ratio

Comment: The OP _had_ aspect ratio preserved in his new image size

Comment: Yes, I said that, but letting the OP know what the method does is always a nice heads-up ;)

Comment: The OP could have simply used `Image#getScaledInstance` and passed a `-1` to either width or height parameter and had the whole done for them as well, but wouldn't be my preferred solution ;)

Answer (score 0):

Small example depending on your code

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;


public class ImageScaler {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            // Load the original image
            BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File(("PATH_TO_YOUR_ORIGINAL_IMAGE")));
            float wh = (float)image.getWidth()/(float)image.getHeight();
            int aspect = Math.round(100*wh);
            // get a scaledInstance from the original image depending on your
            // calculated aspectRation
            Image scaledInstance = image.getScaledInstance(aspect, 100, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
            // convert the Image to BufferedImage
            BufferedImage bi = getScaledBufferedImage(scaledInstance);
            // Write it out
            File outputFile = new File("PATH_TO_SAVE_THE_SCALED_VERSION");
            ImageIO.write(bi, "png", outputFile);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ImageScaler.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Converts a given Image instance to a BufferedImage
     * @param image
     * @return BufferedImage
     */
    private static BufferedImage getScaledBufferedImage(final Image image) {

        // check if image is instanceof BufferedImages
        if(image instanceof BufferedImage) {
            return (BufferedImage)image;
        }

        // create a new BufferedImage
        BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(image.getWidth(null), image.getHeight(null), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

        // get the Graphics Object from the BufferedImage
        Graphics g = bi.getGraphics();
        // draw the Image to the BufferedImage
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
        // dispose the Graphics
        g.dispose();

        return bi;
    }

}
```

Patrick

Comment: Nice example, but why should the OP choose to use it? Also, you're not disposing of the graphics context which could, on some systems, prevent anything from been painted ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer: If you want to be picky, `dispose()` should be invoked from a `finally` block, otherwise an exception may prevent disposal of the native graphics context. ;-)