# Image rendering on java Jframe

Tags: java, swing, jframe, picturebox

I have moved on from C# to java and unable to render the image on java Jframe. Is there any ImageBox component or JFrame method that render the image Like this:

```
JPictureBox box=new JPictureBox("image_path");
JFrame fram=new JFrame();
fram.add(box);
```

Comment: Seems like what you looking for is `JLabel`. Use it's [JLabel.setIcon(...)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html#setIcon-javax.swing.Icon-) method. Hopefully this little [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11372350/1057230) or this detialed [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9866659/1057230), be of some help, on the topic :-)

Comment: but this thing renders the image on whole JFrame. It does notr provide the method to scale the image.

Comment: @Cody Scaling is an expensive operation and all Swing components don't provide that functionality.  You can have a look at [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14548808/scale-the-imageicon-automatically-to-label-size/14553003#14553003) and [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14115950/quality-of-image-after-resize-very-low-java/14116752#14116752) and [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11959758/java-maintaining-aspect-ratio-of-jpanel-background-image/11959928#11959928) for more of discussion on the topic and the issues involved

Comment: @Cody: Play with [Graphics2D](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html), this provides a means to `scale/transform` related functionality.

Comment: @Cody And [something like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25798156/resizing-icon-to-fit-on-jbutton-in-java/25798462#25798462) for an example of how a component might be made to achieve (it uses a `JButton` but the concept would be applicable to a `JLabel`).  You need to remember though, `JLabel` has a lot of additional options, included text, horizontal and vertical alignment for both the text and icon, so it may not be the best base for the solution

Comment: [How to Use Labels](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html) would be the basic answer

Answer (score 1):

This code creates a `JFrame` and displays the file with path `f` in that frame. It uses a `JLabel` as one of the commenters suggests.

```
    public static void display(String f) throws Exception {
        JFrame jf = new JFrame();
        JLabel jl = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(new File(f))));
        jf.add(jl);
        jf.setBounds(0, 0, 200, 200);
        jf.setVisible(true);
        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
```

Note that you would probably want to handle exceptions better, set the size from the image (you can ask the result of `ImageIO.read()` for `.getWidth()` and `.getHeight()`), and so on.

Here is a slightly more complex example where the image changes size to fill its boundary:

```
    public static void display(final String f) throws Exception {
        JFrame jf = new JFrame();
        JPanel jp = new JPanel() {
            private BufferedImage bi = ImageIO.read(new File(f));
            public void paint(Graphics g) {
                Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
                RenderingHints rh = new RenderingHints(
                    RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION,
                    RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BICUBIC);
                g2.setRenderingHints(rh);

                int w = getWidth();
                int h = getHeight();
                g.drawImage(bi, 0, 0, w, h, null);
            }
        };
        jf.add(jp);
        jf.setBounds(0, 0, 400, 200);
        jf.setVisible(true);
        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
```

Note: after reading the links in the comments, I have to recommend *MadProgrammer*'s exhaustive posts on the topic. The only merit of this answer is its short length - but if you want [much better down-scaling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14115950/quality-of-image-after-resize-very-low-java/14116752#14116752), [ratio-preserving scaling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14548808/scale-the-imageicon-automatically-to-label-size/14553003#14553003) or other in-depth image-related, follow those links.