# Java swing jbutton charging old image

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, repaint

i created a custom Java Button like this

```
 public class GraphicPaintedButton extends JButton implements ToPaint{

    protected BufferedImage background;
    private boolean painted = false;

    public GraphicPaintedButton() {

    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        if(painted){
        System.out.println("PAINTING!");
        Dimension size = getSize();
        g.drawImage(background, 0, 0,size.width, size.height,0, 0, background.getWidth(), background.getHeight(), null);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void loadImage(String url){

        painted = true;
        URL imagePath = getClass().getResource(url);
        BufferedImage result = null;
        try {
            result = ImageIO.read(imagePath);
        } catch (IOException | IllegalArgumentException e) {
            System.err.println("Errore, immagine non trovata");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        background = result;
    }
    }
```

Iif i load an image on the button, it calls the repaint,and it's good, the image is shown, when i load a new Image, it calls the repaint again and the new Image is shown. The problem is when i pass the mouse over the button, it calls the rapaint, but loads the old image. Why? And how did it get the old image, as the new one should have replaced it?

Comment: How do you "load a new image"?

Comment: GraphicPaintedButton  button = new GraphicPaintedButton(); button.loadImage("blabla");

Comment: yes i do that too, but i don't think that's the problem, after loadng an image, it displays, i need to delete from the button the old Image, even tho I thought it would do it automatically, or prevent the repaint on mouseover

Comment: I'd use `if (background != null) {` instead of `if(painted){` - because the load method may fail, but you've set the `painted` flag to `true` anyway

Comment: @MadProgrammer This might be the cause.

Comment: I had a play around with your (modified) code and it mostly works

Comment: I would use normal `JButton` with empty text, and disabled borders, with 0 insets and image loaded as `ImageIcon`... And would not bother with painting....

Comment: How do i resize the image? the resize metho asks for the JButton width and height, but i don't have a fixed Dimension, instead the layout organize them (GridBagLayout) and getWidth returns 0.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you want to go this extend and not simply use the `icon` property of the button, but...

First, I'd get rid of the `painted` flag, it runs the risk of allowing the `paintComponent` method to try and paint a `null` image, because the `loadImage` method may fail, but the `painted` flag is always set to `true` - Let's face it, you could easily end up with `painted == true` and `background == null` ... which is not a valid state

Instead, reason about the actual state you're interested in...

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    if (background != null) {
        Dimension size = getSize();
        g.drawImage(background, 0, 0, size.width, size.height, 0, 0, background.getWidth(), background.getHeight(), null);
    }
}
```

I would also change the `loadImage` method

```
public void loadImage(URL url) throws IOException {
    background = ImageIO.read(url);
    revalidate();
    repaint();
}
```

First, don't use `String`, it's meaning is to ambiguous, instead, specify the lowest common parameter you're willing to deal with.

Secondly, the image is either going to load or it's not, if you're not going to deal with the exception, in any meaningful fashion, pass it back to the caller who may be in a better position to deal with it - IMHO

I don't know if this important or not, but I'd also consider overriding the `getPreferredSize` method...

```
@Override
public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
    return background == null ? new Dimension(10, 10) : new Dimension(background.getWidth(), background.getHeight());
}
```

This will at least try and match the button's size to the size of the image

Comment: i removed the painted boolean, and changed the loadImage, but it doesn't remove that it shows the wrong image, can i force not to repaint on mouseover

Comment: hey, ok i tried with the icon, but how do i resize the image to fit the JButton? The resize method needs the height and the width, but i don't have them fixed, but put in a gridBagLayout

Comment: So, know I'm wondering if you're adding the button multiple times, one over the other

Comment: If you want to resize the icon, have a look at [Resizing icon to fit on JButton in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25798156/resizing-icon-to-fit-on-jbutton-in-java/25798462#25798462)