# How do I resize an image in a label that's selected in a classpath resource?

Tags: java, image, swing, jbutton, jlabel

This is the code

```
btnVoltar.setIcon(new ImageIcon(AdicionarRefeição1.class.getResource("/icons/Back Icon.png")));
```

I want to resize it so it fits on a label, but its way too big.

Comment: I think you're thinking backwards, but, `ImageIO.read` will allow you to load an image from the resource bundle, then you could use something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11959758/java-maintaining-aspect-ratio-of-jpanel-background-image/11959928#11959928) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25798156/resizing-icon-to-fit-on-jbutton-in-java/25798462#25798462) to scale it

Comment: How big is "way too big"? 100px? 1000px? Size of Texas? Size of Alaska? Size of the Great Red Spot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this codes here, but then again this post is a duplicate from stackoverflow

```
private ImageIcon image; // where in your case it's your class resource
        Image IMG = image.getImage(); // transform it 
        Image newimg = IMG.getScaledInstance(200, 200,  java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH); // scale it the smooth way 
//Change the 200,200 to the number you prefer to resize it to
        image = new ImageIcon(newimg);  // transform it back
```