# Memory leak while scaling image as background in java swing

Tags: java, image, swing, jlayeredpane

So,
I'm trying to write a function to scale an image and use it as the background, but it allocates a lot of memory and after a few seconds the out of memory exception is raised.
Here's the function that is inside an infinite loop.

```
public static void scale() {
        JLabel background = new JLabel();
        Image imgscale = img.getScaledInstance(back.getWidth(), back.getHeight(), Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
        ImageIcon backgroundImage = new ImageIcon(imgscale);
        background.setIcon(backgroundImage);
        background.setSize(back.getWidth(), back.getHeight());
        jlayeredpane1.add(background, Integer.valueOf(0));
        jlayeredpane1.remove(background);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
```

Comment: Consider providing a [mcve]

Comment: You might also find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11959758/java-maintaining-aspect-ratio-of-jpanel-background-image/11959928#11959928), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14115950/quality-of-image-after-resize-very-low-java/14116752#14116752) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14548808/scale-the-imageicon-automatically-to-label-size/14553003#14553003) helpful

Comment: Why is the `scale()` function in an infinite loop? And why do you add the `background` to the `jlayeredpane1` just to remove it in the next line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the function that is inside an infinite loop.

Wait, what!?

```
public static void scale() {
    JLabel background = new JLabel();
    Image imgscale = img.getScaledInstance(back.getWidth(), back.getHeight(), Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
    ImageIcon backgroundImage = new ImageIcon(imgscale);
    background.setIcon(backgroundImage);
    background.setSize(back.getWidth(), back.getHeight());
    jlayeredpane1.add(background, Integer.valueOf(0));
    jlayeredpane1.remove(background);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Think about that for a second, every time this method is called you are...

- Creating a new instance of `JLabel` (`background`)
- Creating a new instance of `img`, scaled down
- Creating a new instance of `ImageIcon` to wrap around the `Image`
- Applying the `ImageIcon` to the `JLabel`
- Adding the instance of the `JLabel` you just created to the `JLayeredPane`
- Removing the instance of `JLabel` you just created from the `JLayeredPane` ... wait, what!?

And you're wondering why you're running out of memory?!  I've not even mentioned the fact that this is been done within a `static` context.

Add in, if you're doing this within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread, you're going to cause the UI to "freeze" and if you're not doing this within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread, then you're violating the API as Swing is not thread safe.

I would suggest having a look at something like ...

- [Scale the ImageIcon automatically to label size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14548808/scale-the-imageicon-automatically-to-label-size/14553003#14553003)
- [Resizing icon to fit on JButton in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25798156/resizing-icon-to-fit-on-jbutton-in-java/25798462#25798462)
- [How to set a background picture in JPanel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22162398/how-to-set-a-background-picture-in-jpanel/22162430#22162430)

some better ideas on how to achieve your goal