# new saved Image file not Redimensioned?

Tags: java, bufferedimage, javax.imageio

Ok  so  I've been  trying do  read an image and  resize it to a  specified dimension  and save it  into a  package directory,  everything   goes well  but  the image   still  keeps the same  dimensions as the external file,  and  don't  understand why   this is  my  method.

```
    public boolean guardarImagen() {
    boolean imgcreated = false;
    MUbicaciones ub = (MUbicaciones) this.getObject();
    File imagenFile = ub.getImagen();

    //create img  dimensions (supposed to anyways)
    BufferedImage bufim = new BufferedImage(300, 300,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    // asignar la imagen al bufim.
    try {
        bufim = ImageIO.read(imagenFile);
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    // obtener las extensiones de los archivos.
    String ff = imagenFile.getName();
    String formatName = ff.replaceAll("^[\\w]+(\\s)?[^.]", "");
    String fileExtension = ff.replaceAll("^[\\w]+.[^A-Za-z]", "");
    // nuevo archivo que contiene la ubicacion donde se va a guardar la
    // imagen.
    newImageFile = new File(this.getDirImagen() + this.getNombreArchivo()
            + formatName);      
    try {
        // escribe la copia de la imagen en nuevo directorio.
        ImageIO.write(bufim, fileExtension, newImageFile);
        imgcreated = true;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return imgcreated;
}// guardar imagen
```

Comment: Where are you actually resizing the image??

Comment: You might consider having a look at [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11959758/java-maintaining-aspect-ratio-of-jpanel-background-image/11959928#11959928) and [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14115950/quality-of-image-after-resize-very-low-java/14116752#14116752)

Comment: @MadProgrammer, hello,  so I thought the `BufferedImage`   took the new `width,height`  so  looking at  examples would this  do the trick:  `bufim.getScaledInstance(400, 400, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);` ?

Comment: 1- You actually create two `BufferedImage`s, one via `new BufferedImage` and one by `ImageIO`. 2- Yes, `getScaledInstance` can work, but you'd need to paint the result to another `BufferedImage` of the same size (`getScaledInstance` doesn't affect the original, it simply creates a new instance at the desired size) and `ImageIO` won't write `Image` types (it will want a `BufferedImage`...