# Trying to cast an Image to a BufferedImage

Tags: java, user-interface, graphics, exception

I'm writing java code for a game and when creating the health bars I saw an exception that confused me greatly. The code and stack is below:

Code:

```
package com.teamanubiz.pixelhero;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import com.teamanubiz.gameapi.gfx.Sprite;

public class GUIRenderLayer {

  public void renderStatBar(GUIPosition pos, Graphics g, int health, int maxHealth, int mana, int maxMana) {

    Sprite healthBar = null;
    try {
        healthBar = new Sprite(ImageIO.read(new File("res\\gui\\bar.png")));
    } catch (IOException e2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e2.printStackTrace();
    }
    healthBar.crop(0, 0, 128, 32);
    healthBar.scale(256, 32);
    Sprite manaBar = null;
    try {
        manaBar = new Sprite(ImageIO.read(new File("res\\gui\\bar.png")));
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    manaBar.crop(0, 32, 128, 32);
    manaBar.scale(265, 16);
    Sprite temp = null;
    try {
        temp = new Sprite(ImageIO.read(new File("res\\gui\\bar.png")));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    temp.crop(0, 64, 128, 32);
    temp.scale(256, 32);
    Sprite emptyHealth = new Sprite(temp.getCurrent());
    temp.scale(256, 16);
    Sprite emptyMana = new Sprite(temp.getCurrent());

    if (pos == GUIPosition.BOTTOM) {

      double percent_h = health / maxHealth;
      double percent_m = mana / maxMana;

      healthBar.crop(0, 0, (int) ((int) 256 * percent_h), 32);
      manaBar.crop(0, 0, (int) ((int) 256 * percent_m), 16);

      g.drawImage(emptyMana.getCurrent(), 100, 464, null);
      g.drawImage(emptyHealth.getCurrent(), 100, 432, null);
      g.drawImage(healthBar.getCurrent(), 100, 432, null);
      g.drawImage(manaBar.getCurrent(), 100, 464, null);

    }

  }

}
```

This class is referencing a custom library containing the class `Sprite`. It for some reason says that I am trying to cast a `ToolkitImage` to a `BufferedImage` in the below method of **Sprite.java**.

```
public void crop(int xOffset, int yOffset, int width, int height) {

    BufferedImage temp = (BufferedImage) source;

    temp = temp.getSubimage(xOffset, yOffset, width, height);

    source = temp;

}
```

The variable `source` is an instance of an `Image` that is a field in **Sprite.java**

The stack below claims I am creating a `ToolkitImage` despite the fact `new ImageIcon("res\\gui\\bar.png").getImage()` returns only an `Image`. I do not convert the `Image` to a `ToolkitImage` ever in the code. This makes it extremely confusing.

Stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: sun.awt.image.ToolkitImage cannot be cast to java.awt.image.BufferedImage
    at com.teamanubiz.gameapi.gfx.Sprite.crop(Sprite.java:48)
    at com.teamanubiz.pixelhero.GUIRenderLayer.renderStatBar(GUIRenderLayer.java:55)
    at com.teamanubiz.pixelhero.GameWindow.tick(GameWindow.java:14)
    at com.teamanubiz.gameapi.Display.paint(Display.java:95)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$1300(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: sun.awt.image.ToolkitImage cannot be cast to java.awt.image.BufferedImage
    at com.teamanubiz.gameapi.gfx.Sprite.crop(Sprite.java:48)
    at com.teamanubiz.pixelhero.GUIRenderLayer.renderStatBar(GUIRenderLayer.java:55)
    at com.teamanubiz.pixelhero.GameWindow.tick(GameWindow.java:14)
    at com.teamanubiz.gameapi.Display.paint(Display.java:95)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$1300(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: sun.awt.image.ToolkitImage cannot be cast to java.awt.image.BufferedImage
    at com.teamanubiz.gameapi.gfx.Sprite.crop(Sprite.java:48)
    at com.teamanubiz.pixelhero.GUIRenderLayer.renderStatBar(GUIRenderLayer.java:55)
    at com.teamanubiz.pixelhero.GameWindow.tick(GameWindow.java:14)
    at com.teamanubiz.gameapi.Display.paint(Display.java:95)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$1300(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`BufferedImage` is a type of `Image`, but `Image` is not a type `BufferedImage`, you could, for example, cast `BufferedImage` to an `Image`.

Instead of using `ImageIcon` to load the image, use `ImageIO.read`, which returns a `BufferedImage`

So instead of...

```
 Sprite healthBar = new Sprite((Image)new ImageIcon("res\\gui\\bar.png").getImage()); // I Never Instatiated a ToolkitImage!!!!!!!!
```

*Nb: `ImageIcon` delegates the actual loading of the image to `Toolkit` and wraps it in a Icon interface*

Use something like...

```
Sprite healthBar = new Sprite(ImageIO.read(new File("res\\gui\\bar.png")));
```

Comment: I just did that and the Exception changed. `at com.teamanubiz.pixelhero.GUIRenderLayer.renderStatBar(GUIRenderLayer.java:55)` now it is inside the **if** statement in GUIRenderLayer at the first `crop()` reference.

Comment: I have also thought out that the Images could be converted by the Java API when I'm using `Image.getScaledInstance(int,int)` in `Sprite.scale(int,int)`.

Comment: "I have also thought out that the Images could be converted by the Java API when I'm using Image.getScaledInstance(int,int) in Sprite.scale(int,int)." I have found this is true, but I have no idea how to work around it. I don't have any choice but to scale the image.

Comment: You can scale a `BufferedImage` using a verity of techniques, the preferred is usually to use the `Graphics2D` API, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11959758/java-maintaining-aspect-ratio-of-jpanel-background-image/11959928#11959928) and [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14115950/quality-of-image-after-resize-very-low-java/14116752#14116752). You should also have a look at [The Perils of Image.getScaledInstance()](https://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/04/03/perils-of-image-getscaledinstance.html)

Comment: I have no idea how I fixed it. I changed Sprite.java to make the scaled image a `BufferedImage`, and then the Sprite didn't scale, so then I rolled back my library that Sprite was being used in, and for some odd reason, it suddenly worked without a problem. I'm stumped. Thanks for your help, though! `ImageIO.read()` works like a charm. I looked at the page you sent me. I had no idea you could scale the image right as it's rendering. You learn something new every day...

Answer (score 2):

No you don't "convert" the Image to a ToolKitImage, but that's what the JVM is giving you when you call `new ImageIcon("res\\gui\\bar.png").getImage()`, and not a BufferedImage. The ImageIcon API states that `getImage()` returns an object of Image type, but does not specify what type of Image. Since Image is an interface, you *know* that there must be some concrete type underlying the returned Image object. If you need a BufferedImage you could one, and draw this Image into it.

Myself, I wouldn't even use an ImageIcon here if I wanted a BufferedImage, but rather would use `ImageIO.read(...)` which returns a BufferedImage.

So....

```
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("res/gui/bar.png"));
Sprite healthBar  = new Sprite(img);
```