# Poor Perfomance when resizing an Java JFrame with a pictured JPanel in it

Tags: java, resize, jframe, jpanel, scale

I managed it to create a JPanel with a special picture as Background and put this JPanel in a JFrame.
Everytime a resize the JFrame the JPanel and the picture in it with be also resized. The ComponentListener is registered to the JFrame which notifies modifications in its size.

Here's the code:

```
package examples;

import images.MyImage;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.ComponentAdapter;
import java.awt.event.ComponentEvent;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class example3 {

    private static JPanel panel = new MyPanel();
    private static JFrame frame = new JFrame();

    private static class MyPanel extends JPanel {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private int width = 0;
        private int height = 0;
        public static final int DEFAULT_WIDTH = 400;
        public static final int DEFAULT_HEIGHT = 100;

        public MyPanel(int width, int heigth) {
            super.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            setWidth(width);
            setHeigth(heigth);
        }

        public MyPanel() {
            super.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            setWidth(DEFAULT_WIDTH);
            setHeigth(DEFAULT_HEIGHT);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION,
                    RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING,
                    RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_SPEED);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                    RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            g2d.drawImage(MyImage.IMAGE_BLUE_BLACKGROUND, 0, 0,
                    getMyPanelWidth(), getMyPanelHeight(), null);

            g2d.dispose();
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension preferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(getMyPanelWidth(), getMyPanelHeight());
        }

        private void setWidth(int width) {
            this.width = width;
        }

        private void setHeigth(int height) {
            this.height = height;
        }

        private int getMyPanelHeight() {
            return height;
        }

        private int getMyPanelWidth() {
            return width;
        }

    }

    private static class ComponentHandler extends ComponentAdapter{

        @Override
        public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
            super.componentResized(e);
            frame.remove(panel);
            frame.getContentPane().add(
                    new MyPanel(frame.getSize().width, frame.getSize().height),
                    BorderLayout.CENTER);

            frame.repaint();
            frame.revalidate();

        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        frame.add(panel);
        frame.addComponentListener(new ComponentHandler());

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

The problem is that I'm getting scaling errors:
[image]

Is it because the *Event Dispatch Thread* can not handle all the resize-Events which is fired by the resize-method? Is there any satisfying solution?

Comment: Generally speaking, don't resize the image within the paint method

Comment: You could try something along the lines of this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27219914/how-to-increase-drawing-speed-of-jpicturebox-for-large-image/27220548#27220548), which consolates changes to the image to as few updates as possible and generates a low quality (quick scale) and high quality (slow scale) result...