# Java Swing Graphics performance issues

Tags: java, performance, swing, graphics

I'm trying to learn Java graphics programming.

I wrote a program which loads an image, and draws it to the screen. The user can move the image around with the keyboard.

The problem is the movement is really choppy and not smooth at all.

The program doesn't seem to be using too much CPU or memory:

```
$ ps -p (pgrep java) -o %cpu,%mem,cmd
%CPU %MEM CMD
 5.5  0.3 java -jar app.jar
```

What can I do to make it so it isn't so choppy?

## Details

```
$ java --version
java 21.0.2 2024-01-16 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 21.0.2+13-LTS-58)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 21.0.2+13-LTS-58, mixed mode, sharing)
```

```
$ mvn --version
Apache Maven 3.6.3
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 21.0.2, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-21-oracle-x64
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "6.5.0-15-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

```java
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

class Character {
  int x, y;
  BufferedImage image;

  public Character(String sprite_sheet, int x, int y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;

    try {
      image = ImageIO.read(new File(sprite_sheet));
      image = image.getSubimage(0, 0, 16, 16);

      Image tmp = image.getScaledInstance(64, 64, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
      image = new BufferedImage(64, 64, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
      image.getGraphics().drawImage(tmp, 0, 0, null);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  public void draw(Graphics g) {
    g.drawImage(image, x, y, null);
  }

  public void move(int dx, int dy) {
    x += dx;
    y += dy;
  }
}

class KeyboardState {
  boolean left, right, up, down;
}

class Game extends JPanel {
  Character character;
  KeyboardState keyboardState;
  int numPaints = 0;

  @Override
  public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);

    if (character != null) {
      character.draw(g);
    }

    numPaints++;
  }

  public void moveCharacter(int dx, int dy) {
    if (character != null) {
      character.move(dx, dy);
    }
  }

  public void update() {
    if (keyboardState.left) {
      character.move(-5, 0);
    }

    if (keyboardState.right) {
      character.move(5, 0);
    }

    if (keyboardState.up) {
      character.move(0, -5);
    }

    if (keyboardState.down) {
      character.move(0, 5);
    }

    repaint();
  }

  public void start() {
    Timer timer = new Timer(1000 / 30, new ActionListener() {
      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        update();
      }
    });

    timer.start();
  }
}

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("TODO");

    Game game = new Game();
    game.character = new Character(
        "sprite-sheet.png",
        100, 100);
    game.keyboardState = new KeyboardState();

    frame.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
      @Override
      public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        int key = e.getKeyCode();
        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
          game.keyboardState.left = true;
        } else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
          game.keyboardState.right = true;
        } else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
          game.keyboardState.up = true;
        } else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
          game.keyboardState.down = true;
        } else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE) {
          System.out.println("Num paints: " + game.numPaints);
          System.exit(0);
        }
      }

      @Override
      public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        int key = e.getKeyCode();
        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
          game.keyboardState.left = false;
        } else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
          game.keyboardState.right = false;
        } else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
          game.keyboardState.up = false;
        } else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
          game.keyboardState.down = false;
        }
      }
    });

    frame.add(game);
    frame.setSize(800, 600);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    game.start();
  }
}
```

Comment: Swing is really creeky old these days. I'd recommend you pick up (J)OGL - it's much better for games.

Comment: @ControlAltDel Don’t forget about JavaFX, which itself uses graphics acceleration.

Comment: I don't have any issues (macOS 14.3.1/Java 17.0.7), although I would recommend using [key bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase%2Ftutorial%2Fuiswing%2F%2F/misc/keybinding.html) over `KeyListener` and registering those against the `GamePanel` directly instead of the frame

Comment: See also [*Initial Threads*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).

Comment: You also want to have a look at [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27219914/how-to-increase-drawing-speed-of-jpicturebox-for-large-image/27220548#27220548) as you may need to convert the `BufferedImage` to a compatible color model for the graphics device, has helped me in the past