# Java image zooming japplet

Tags: java, swing

Im trying to make an applet that will allow me to open, zoom in and out of an image. Ive got a working applet going, but am having trouble with the zoom. Any ideas on where to head from here?

This is what I have so far

ImageZoom

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.io.*;



public class ImageZoom extends JApplet implements ActionListener
{
JPanel jpanel, pane2;
JLabel image;
JButton open_file, zoom_in, zoom_out;
Image img;
JFileChooser fc;
Zoom zP;

@Override
public void init() 
{
   setSize(450,450);
   buttonLayout();
   filechooser();
   imgLayout();
   zP = new Zoom();
}   

public void imgLayout()
{
    pane2 = new JPanel();
    pane2.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    image = new JLabel("");
    pane2.add(image,BorderLayout.CENTER);
}

public void buttonLayout()
{
    jpanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());

    open_file = new JButton("Open file");
    open_file.addActionListener(this);
    jpanel.add(open_file);

    zoom_in = new JButton("Zoom In");
    zoom_in.addActionListener(this);
    jpanel.add(zoom_in);

    zoom_out = new JButton("Zoom Out");
   zoom_out.addActionListener(this);
    jpanel.add(zoom_out);

    add( jpanel, BorderLayout.NORTH );
}

public void filechooser()
{
    fc = new JFileChooser();
    fc.setCurrentDirectory(new File(
            System.getProperty("user.home")));
}    



@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) 
{

    if(ae.getSource() == open_file)
    {
    int result = fc.showOpenDialog(null );
    if(result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
    {
        File file = fc.getSelectedFile();
        String sname = file.getAbsolutePath();
        image = new JLabel("", new ImageIcon(sname), JLabel.CENTER);
        jpanel.add(image, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        jpanel.revalidate();
        jpanel.repaint();
    }
  }    
    else if(ae.getSource() == zoom_in)
    {
        zP.increaseSize();
    }
    else if(ae.getSource() == zoom_out)
    {
        zP.decreaseSize();
    }
}
}
```

Zoom

```
import java.awt.*;  
import java.awt.event.*;  
import java.applet.*;  


class Zoom extends Panel
{  
MediaTracker tracker;  
Image img;  
Dimension imgSize,iniSize;  

public Zoom()
{  
setSize(400,275);  
img =Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("image"); // here u give ur own image name  
tracker=new MediaTracker(this);  
tracker.addImage(img,1);  

try{  
tracker.waitForAll();  
}  
catch(InterruptedException ie){  
System.out.println("Error in loading image");  
}  

  imgSize=iniSize=new Dimension(img.getWidth(this),img.getHeight(this));  

}  

@Override
public Dimension getPreferredSize(){  
return new Dimension(imgSize);  

}  

public void decreaseSize()
{  
    int x=10*imgSize.width/100;  
    int y=10*imgSize.height/100;  

    imgSize=new Dimension(imgSize.width-x,imgSize.height-y);  

    if(getWidth()>iniSize.width)
    {  
    setSize(imgSize);  
    getParent().doLayout();  
    }  
repaint();  
} 

    public void increaseSize()
{  
    int x=10*imgSize.width/100;   
    int y=10*imgSize.height/100;  
    imgSize = new Dimension(imgSize.width+x,imgSize.height+y);   
    if(imgSize.width>iniSize.width)
{  
    setSize(imgSize);  
    getParent().doLayout();  
}
 repaint();
}

}  // class Zoom
```

Comment: You might like to take a look at [How to Use Menus](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html), in particular the `JMenuBar` and [What Applets Can and Cannot Do](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/security.html)

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to respond. I am not using a menu, really, its 3 buttons in an applet - open, zoom in and zoom out. I can get it to open the picture, all Im having issue with now is enlarging and decreasing its size.

Comment: Sorry, sure there was a menu in there some where :P

Answer (score 3):

You could continue to use a `JLabel` and scale the image and reset the `JLabel`s `icon` property, or you could create a custom component dedicated to the job...

To start with, we need to display the image...

```
public class ZoomPane extends JPanel {

    private BufferedImage master;
    private Image scaled;
    private float scale = 1f;

    public ZoomPane() {
        try {
            master = ImageIO.read(new File("..."));
            scaled = master;
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return scaled != null ? new Dimension(scaled.getWidth(this), scaled.getHeight(this)) : new Dimension(200, 200);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        if (scaled != null) {
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            int x = (getWidth() - scaled.getWidth(this)) / 2;
            int y = (getHeight() - scaled.getHeight(this)) / 2;
            g2d.drawImage(scaled, x, y, this);
            g2d.dispose();
        }
    }

}
```

Now, you could use a `MouseWheelListener` to scale the image...

```
addMouseWheelListener(new MouseWheelListener() {
    @Override
    public void mouseWheelMoved(MouseWheelEvent e) {
        if (e.getWheelRotation() < 0) {
            scale -= 0.1;
        } else {
            scale += 0.1;
        }
        scaleBy(scale);
    }
});
```

And because you'll probably want to allow the users a few different methods to scale the image, a nice convenience method....

```
public void scaleBy(float amount) {
    scale += amount;
    scale = Math.min(Math.max(scale, 0.1f), 200);
    scaled = master.getScaledInstance(
                    Math.round(master.getWidth() * scale),
                    Math.round(master.getHeight() * scale),
                    Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
    revalidate();
    repaint();
}
```

Now, it'd probably be nice to allow the user to use the <kbd>+</kbd> and <kbd>-</kbd> keys, for this, we'll want some kind of `Action`...

```
public class ZoomAction extends AbstractAction {
    private ZoomPane zoomPane;
    private float zoomAmount;

    public ZoomAction(ZoomPane zoomPane, String name, float zoomAmount) {
        this.zoomAmount = zoomAmount;
        this.zoomPane = zoomPane;
        putValue(NAME, name);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        zoomPane.scaleBy(zoomAmount);
        System.out.println("...");
    }

}
```

This allows us to bind keyboard actions, buttons and menus and re-use the same basic code to do it...

```
InputMap im = getInputMap(WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
ActionMap am = getActionMap();
im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ADD, 0), "zoom-in");
im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_SUBTRACT, 0), "zoom-out");

am.put("zoom-in", new ZoomAction(this, "Zoom in", 0.1f));
am.put("zoom-out", new ZoomAction(this, "Zoom out", -0.1f));
```

This example works with the numpad <kbd>+</kbd> and <kbd>-</kbd> keys.

All this functionality should be added directly within the `ZoomPane`

You can re-use the `ZoomAction` in your menus...

```
JMenuBar mb = new JMenuBar();
JMenu pictureMenu = new JMenu("Picture");
pictureMenu.add(new ZoomAction(zoomPane, "Zoom In", 0.1f));
pictureMenu.add(new ZoomAction(zoomPane, "Zoom Out", -0.1f));
mb.add(pictureMenu);
```

And even in you buttons...

```
JPanel buttons = new JPanel();
buttons.add(new JButton(new ZoomAction(zoomPane, "Zoom In", 0.1f)));
buttons.add(new JButton(new ZoomAction(zoomPane, "Zoom Out", -0.1f)));
frame.add(buttons, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

## Warning

The scaling is pretty rough and ready, you should consider taking a look at:

- [The Perils of Image.getScaledInstance()](https://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/04/03/perils-of-image-getscaledinstance.html)
- [Java: maintaining aspect ratio of JPanel background image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11959758/java-maintaining-aspect-ratio-of-jpanel-background-image/11959928#11959928)
- [Quality of Image after resize very low -- Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14115950/quality-of-image-after-resize-very-low-java/14116752#14116752)

... for more details

And finally, hacking it all together, as a runnable example...

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseWheelEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseWheelListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.ActionMap;
import javax.swing.InputMap;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                ZoomPane zoomPane = new ZoomPane();

                JMenuBar mb = new JMenuBar();
                JMenu pictureMenu = new JMenu("Picture");
                pictureMenu.add(new ZoomAction(zoomPane, "Zoom In", 0.1f));
                pictureMenu.add(new ZoomAction(zoomPane, "Zoom Out", -0.1f));

                mb.add(pictureMenu);

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setJMenuBar(mb);
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(zoomPane);

                JPanel buttons = new JPanel();
                buttons.add(new JButton(new ZoomAction(zoomPane, "Zoom In", 0.1f)));
                buttons.add(new JButton(new ZoomAction(zoomPane, "Zoom Out", -0.1f)));
                frame.add(buttons, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class ZoomPane extends JPanel {

        private BufferedImage master;
        private Image scaled;
        private float scale = 1f;

        public ZoomPane() {
            try {
                master = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\Users\\shane\\Dropbox\\MegaTokyo\\megatokyo_omnibus_1_3_cover_by_fredrin-d4oupef.jpg"));
                scaled = master;

                addMouseWheelListener(new MouseWheelListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void mouseWheelMoved(MouseWheelEvent e) {
                        if (e.getWheelRotation() < 0) {
                            scale -= 0.1;
                        } else {
                            scale += 0.1;
                        }
                        scaleBy(scale);
                    }
                });

                InputMap im = getInputMap(WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
                ActionMap am = getActionMap();
                im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ADD, 0), "zoom-in");
                im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_SUBTRACT, 0), "zoom-out");

                am.put("zoom-in", new ZoomAction(this, "Zoom in", 0.1f));
                am.put("zoom-out", new ZoomAction(this, "Zoom out", -0.1f));
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public void scaleBy(float amount) {
            scale += amount;
            scale = Math.min(Math.max(scale, 0.1f), 200);
            scaled = master.getScaledInstance(
                            Math.round(master.getWidth() * scale),
                            Math.round(master.getHeight() * scale),
                            Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
            revalidate();
            repaint();
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return scaled != null ? new Dimension(scaled.getWidth(this), scaled.getHeight(this)) : new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            if (scaled != null) {
                Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
                int x = (getWidth() - scaled.getWidth(this)) / 2;
                int y = (getHeight() - scaled.getHeight(this)) / 2;
                g2d.drawImage(scaled, x, y, this);
                g2d.dispose();
            }
        }

    }

    public class ZoomAction extends AbstractAction {
        private ZoomPane zoomPane;
        private float zoomAmount;

        public ZoomAction(ZoomPane zoomPane, String name, float zoomAmount) {
            this.zoomAmount = zoomAmount;
            this.zoomPane = zoomPane;
            putValue(NAME, name);
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            zoomPane.scaleBy(zoomAmount);
            System.out.println("...");
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: this runs and looks great - how can I go about adding an open file button?

Comment: Well, you could add a new JMenu/JMenuItem, you'll have to modify the ZoomPanel to allow you to pass the master image to it as well (via a getter of some kind), which would need to call scaleBy and pass it 0 to scale to the current scale factor or reset the scale factor back to 1