# Resize and Redraw a image in a JPanel

Tags: java, image, swing

I'm creating a simple java program to load a image and zoom in/out the image.
So far I have been able load the picture and zoom it. But when drawing the zoomed out image I can still see the previous image on the JPanel.

> Code for loading the image

```
JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
fileChooser.setFileFilter(new FileNameExtensionFilter("Images(jpg,png,gif)", "jpg","png","gif"));
int opt = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(this);
if(opt  == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
    String filePath = fileChooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();
    try {
        bufImage = ImageIO.read(fileChooser.getSelectedFile());
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ImageZoom.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    image = new ImageIcon(filePath);
    imgWidth = image.getIconWidth();
    imgHeight = image.getIconHeight();

    imagePanel.getGraphics().drawImage(image.getImage(), 0, 100, image.getIconWidth(), image.getIconHeight(), imagePanel);
}
```

> Code for zooming in

```
double scale_factor = 1.5;
imagePanel.getGraphics().drawImage(image.getImage(), 0, 100, (int)(imgWidth*=scale_factor), (int)(imgHeight*=scale_factor), imagePanel);
```

> Code for zooming out

```
double scale_factor = 0.5;
imagePanel.getGraphics().drawImage(image.getImage(), 0, 100, (int)(imgWidth*=scale_factor), (int)(imgHeight*=scale_factor), imagePanel);
```

Can some one please suggest a way to only have the resized image on the panel?
This is how zooming out looks like. same problem occurs when opening a new picture.
I tried repainting the panel but then everything vanishes.

[image: This is how zooming out looks like]

Comment: @LuxxMiner Tried it. Nothing is shown on the panel. I just get an empty window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `imagePanel.getGraphics()` isn't how custom painting works in Swing.  Instead, create a custom class which extends from something like `JPanel` and override it's `paintComponent` method, painting your scaled image there (making sure to call `super.paintComponent` first)

See [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details

For example:

- [zoom using mouse and graphics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19643637/zoom-using-mouse-and-graphics/19646246#19646246)
- [Java image zooming japplet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27498104/java-image-zooming-japplet/27498381#27498381)
- [Jpanel resize on repaint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12797933/jpanel-resize-on-repaint/12798480#12798480)

Comment: I tried what  you said and I cannot see my image on the panel.
Here is the code I used : http://paste.ubuntu.com/11952468/
Can you please check it and let me know what is the mistake I made

Comment: Your draw panel should be a separate component, you currently have a bunch of other components on your draw panel which are likely painting over the image

Comment: It's also likely you have a NullPointException, as the Image won't have been loaded before the components Tis painted. You should also not be calling repaint directly or indirectly from within any paint method

Comment: If not to call repaint how should I redraw the image when I'm loading a new image?
And I'm not getting a NullPointerException. 
Can you please give me a example?

Comment: You can call repaint, just not from within any `paint` methods, otherwise you set up an infinite loop which will consume your CPU cycles.  I've already linked 3 examples

Comment: Thanks for the help. I managed to get it fixed. Here is the working code http://paste.ubuntu.com/11952695/