# Resize an image using Java

Tags: java, image, image-resizing, javax.imageio, jai

I have a JPEG Master Image which is of a dimension and an input Jpeg image of another dimension . So , I have written the following code to convert an image from one dimension to the other dimension.
This code works fine when the input images are of dimensions around 900 * 700 and the master image of dimension 1200 * 800 .
It does not work when the master/ input images are around dimensions like 3400*1900 and 4400*2400.
Can anyone tell me where I went wrong!

```
public void checkSizeandResize(String file1, String file2){

   BufferedImage scaled = null;
   BufferedImage image1 = null;
   BufferedImage image2 = null;
   Graphics2D graphics2d = null;
   try{
    image1 = imageToBufferedImage(loadJPG(file1));
    image2 = imageToBufferedImage(loadJPG(file2));
    if(image1.getHeight()!=image2.getHeight() || image1.getWidth()!=image2.getWidth()){

            scaled = new BufferedImage(image2.getWidth(),image2.getHeight(), image2.getType());
            graphics2d =  scaled.createGraphics();
            graphics2d.setComposite(AlphaComposite.Src);
            graphics2d.drawImage(image1, 0, 0,null);
            graphics2d.dispose();
            ImageIO.write(image1, extension,new File(file2));

        }
    }
    catch(Exception exception)
    {
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
        scaled = null;
        image1 = null;
        image2 = null;
        graphics2d = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: What does the imageToBufferedImage(loadJPG(...)) do? You do realise that this isn't actually scaling anything? Do you get any error output (like maybe out of memory)?

Comment: This method just coverts Image to buffered java.awt.Image like BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(img.getWidth(null), img.getHeight(null), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

Comment: Any reason why you can't use ImageIO.read?

Comment: I did not see any error , but It does not convert to the required dimension

Comment: You might like to take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11959758/java-maintaining-aspect-ratio-of-jpanel-background-image/11959928#11959928) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14115950/quality-of-image-after-resize-very-low-java/14116752#14116752)

Comment: Please clarify "it does not work". It creates an empty image? The image is not resized?

Comment: The image is not Resized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I did a quick test (using `ImageIO.read` as you've not provided all the code) with an image going from 6144x4096 to 7680x4800 without a problem

But I did notice that you are writing `image1` instead of `scaled`

```
ImageIO.write(image1, extension,new File(file2));
```

Should probably be

```
ImageIO.write(scaled, extension,new File(file2));
```

You should also beware, that this isn't actually "scaling" the image so much as just changing the size of the resulting bitmap (`image1` will remain at it's original size pixel size and painted within the `scaled` boundaries unmodified)

If you're actually interested in changing the physical size of the image to match the corresponding boundaries, you might consider having a look at [Java: maintaining aspect ratio of JPanel background image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11959758/java-maintaining-aspect-ratio-of-jpanel-background-image/11959928#11959928) and [Quality of Image after resize very low -- Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14115950/quality-of-image-after-resize-very-low-java/14116752#14116752)

Comment: Do you have any idea on how OP's code appeared to work with the smaller images?

Comment: @Jongware I think "appeared to work" is the phrase there.  I had to scratch my head a few times trying to figure out why I wasn't getting the results I was expecting till I spotted the problem :P

Comment: I tried from the first link , It shows error as unsupported operation.            scaled = image1.getScaledInstance(image2.getWidth(null),image2.getHeight(null), Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);

    graphics2d =  scaled.getGraphics();

Comment: @BYKR On which line? There are two there? And you're importing `java.awt.Image`?

Comment: The answer which you gave worked . But you give 2 links in the previous comments . So, I tried using the first link to achieve the task . The first link did not work for me . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11959758/java-maintaining-aspect-ratio-of-jpanel-background-image/11959928#11959928

Comment: @BYKR Yes, I understand, but you pasted two lines of code you comment, and I was trying to figure out which one didn't work.  The fact that it's not working for you is surprising because I've been using it for 15+ years.

Comment: Forgive me If I am wrong , As I am just a beginner.

Comment: Image scaled = null;

   Graphics graphics2d = null;

   Image image1 = loadJPG(file1);

   Image image2 = loadJPG(file2);
   
   scaled = image1.getScaledInstance(image2.getWidth(null),image2.getHeight(null), Image.SCALE_SMOOTH); 
   
   graphics2d = scaled.getGraphics();
   
   graphics2d.drawImage(scaled, image2.getWidth(null),image2.getHeight(null),null); throws java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: getGraphics() not valid for images created with createImage(producer) . I have to work without using applets.

Comment: Well, if you're able to use `ImageIO.write`, why not use `ImageIO.read` instead?

Comment: Finally after using graphics2d.drawImage(image1, 0, 0,image2.getWidth(),image2.getHeight(),null); It worked. Thank you