# Refresh Image in JLabel with Timer

Tags: java, swing, timer, jlabel, imageicon

I´m currently working on a little programm witch displays pictures from a website in a little Swing GUI. The Problem is, that every time the picture changes a new frame pops up instead of refreshing the JLable.

I have no idea how to realize this after trying a few attempts with different methods.

It would be nice if you could give me a little hint.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;


public class PageReader extends JFrame {

    JLabel picture;
    static String[] viewable;
    int counter;
    static String urlString;
    Image image;
    URL url;

    public PageReader(int pos) throws IOException
    {
        urlString = "http:"+viewable[pos];

        url = new URL(urlString);
        image = ImageIO.read(url);

        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(image); 

        picture = new JLabel();
        picture.setIcon(icon);


        int breite = icon.getImage().getWidth(this);
        int hoehe = icon.getImage().getHeight(this);


        do
        {
            if(hoehe>400)
            {
                breite *= 0.75;
                hoehe *= 0.75;
                icon.setImage(icon.getImage().getScaledInstance(breite, hoehe, image.SCALE_DEFAULT));
            }

            if(hoehe<400)
            {
                hoehe *= 1.2;
                breite *=1.2;
                icon.setImage(icon.getImage().getScaledInstance(breite, hoehe, image.SCALE_DEFAULT));
            }
        }while(hoehe>400&&hoehe<300);


        icon.setImage(icon.getImage().getScaledInstance(breite, hoehe, image.SCALE_DEFAULT));


        JPanel anzeige = new JPanel();
        anzeige.add(picture, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        setContentPane(anzeige);


        pack();
        setResizable(false);
        setVisible(true);
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String meineURL = "http://www.pr0gramm.com/static/";

         URL url = new URL(meineURL);

         InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
         BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

         // Kompletten Seiteninhalt auslesen
         String line ="";
         String quelltext ="";

         while((line = br.readLine()) != null)
         {
         quelltext += line + "\r\n";
         }

         // Reader Schließen
         br.close();
         isr.close();

         String test = quelltext.substring(1708);
         String[] parts = test.split("<a href=");


         for(int i=1; i<parts.length; i++)
         {
             parts[i]=parts[i].substring(1,15);
         }

         viewable = new String[parts.length];

         for(int i = 1; i<(parts.length-1); i++)
         {
             String sitePath = "http://pr0gramm.com"+parts[i];

             meineURL = sitePath;

             url = new URL(meineURL);

             isr = new InputStreamReader(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
             br = new BufferedReader(isr);

             // Kompletten Seiteninhalt auslesen
             line ="";
             quelltext ="";

             while((line = br.readLine()) != null)
             {
             quelltext += line + "\r\n";
             }

             CharSequence picPath = quelltext.subSequence(quelltext.indexOf("//img.pr0gramm.com/"), quelltext.indexOf("//img.pr0gramm.com/")+50);

             viewable[i] = picPath.toString();

             // Seiteninhalt ausgeben
             //System.out.println(quelltext);
             System.out.println(viewable[i]);
         }

         System.out.println("\nLink-Counter: "+viewable.length);
         //System.out.println("//img.pr0gramm.com/2015/06/25/87fd872bde0ab593.jpg");

         new PageReader(4);
         //System.out.println("\n \n \n Sub \n \n"+test);
         for(int i = 1; i<viewable.length; i++)
         {
             if(!(viewable[i].contains(".web")))
             {
                url = new URL("http:"+viewable[i]);

                new PageReader(i);

                System.out.println("test"+i);
                urlString = "http:"+viewable[i];
                Thread.sleep(5000);
             }
         }


    }

}
```

This is my current code.

Comment: That would be because each time you change the picture, rather then simply changing the lable's icon, you crate a new instance `PageReader` which extends from a `JFrame`.  This pretty much just screams `SwingWorker` to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by taking a look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) and [Worker Threads and SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html)

You might also like to take a look at [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) as using `String#substring` etc to parse html is a really bad idea

Swing is single threaded, meaining your can't block the Event Dispatching Thread with blocking or long running processes (like `Thread.sleep`), but it is also not thread safe, meaning you shouldn't modify it from outside of EDT either.

To this end, `SwingWorker` presents a reasonable solution, as it can process the html and image downloading outside of the EDT, but provides a number of ways you can resync updates to the EDT.

To start with, you need to be updating the `JLabel`'s `icon` property and not creating new instances of `PageReader`, which is one of the (many) reasons we generally discourage people from extending from `JFrame`.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.List;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private JLabel label;

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            label = new JLabel("Loading...");
            label.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
            label.setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
            add(label);
            ImageWorker worker = new ImageWorker(label);
            worker.execute();
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(400, 400);
        }

        public class ImageWorker extends SwingWorker<Object, Image> {

            private JLabel output;

            public ImageWorker(JLabel output) {
                this.output = output;
            }

            @Override
            protected void process(List<Image> chunks) {
                output.setText(null);
                output.setIcon(new ImageIcon(chunks.get(chunks.size() - 1)));
            }

            @Override
            protected Object doInBackground() throws Exception {
                String meineURL = "http://www.pr0gramm.com/static/";

                URL url = new URL(meineURL);

                String quelltext = "";
                try (InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(url.openConnection().getInputStream()); BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr)) {

                    // Kompletten Seiteninhalt auslesen
                    String line = "";

                    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                        quelltext += line + "\r\n";
                    }

                }

                String test = quelltext.substring(1708);
                String[] parts = test.split("<a href=");

                for (int i = 1; i < parts.length; i++) {
                    parts[i] = parts[i].substring(1, 15);
                }

                String[] viewable = new String[parts.length];

                for (int i = 1; i < (parts.length - 1); i++) {
                    String sitePath = "http://pr0gramm.com" + parts[i];

                    meineURL = sitePath;

                    url = new URL(meineURL);

                    try (InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(url.openConnection().getInputStream()); BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr)) {

                        // Kompletten Seiteninhalt auslesen
                        String line = "";
                        quelltext = "";

                        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                            quelltext += line + "\r\n";
                        }

                        CharSequence picPath = quelltext.subSequence(quelltext.indexOf("//img.pr0gramm.com/"), quelltext.indexOf("//img.pr0gramm.com/") + 50);

                        viewable[i] = picPath.toString();

                    }
                }

                System.out.println("\nLink-Counter: " + viewable.length);

                for (int i = 1; i < viewable.length; i++) {
                    if (!(viewable[i].contains(".web"))) {
                        url = new URL("http:" + viewable[i]);

                        System.out.println("Reading " + url);
                        BufferedImage original = ImageIO.read(url);
                        Image image = original;

                        if (original.getWidth() > original.getHeight()) {
                            image = original.getScaledInstance(400, -1, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
                        } else {
                            image = original.getScaledInstance(-1, 400, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
                        }

                        publish(image);

                        System.out.println("test" + i);
                        Thread.sleep(5000);
                    }
                }

                return null;

            }

        }

    }

}
```

Should also have a look at [The try-with-resources Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) for better ideas on how to manage your resources

I didn't want to introduce more code into the example, but you should avoid using `getScaledInstance` if you can, see [The Perils of Image.getScaledInstance()](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/04/03/perils-of-image-getscaledinstance.html) for more details.

You can take a look at [Java: maintaining aspect ratio of JPanel background image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11959758/java-maintaining-aspect-ratio-of-jpanel-background-image/11959928#11959928) and [Quality of Image after resize very low -- Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14115950/quality-of-image-after-resize-very-low-java/14116752#14116752) for alternatives

Comment: Thank you a lot. I will take a look at your recommended links. Your provided code will be a good help to make my own code better

Comment: Is there a way to add a scrollbar if the image is very large ?

Comment: Have a look at [How to Use Scroll Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html) for more details.  Essentially, you want to wrap the `JLabel` in a `JScrollPane` and add the `JScrollPane` to the view

Answer (score 0):

I can't understand the variable naming conventions due to the different language.But, from what I can understand,I think u should not call`new PageReader()` on every update.

Instead you should call something like `update(int pos)`

```
public void update(int pos)
{
    //The Code that went into your constructor
}
```

This will ensure that the same `JFrame` is reused instead of a new one being created.

Also I don't think u should initialize a new `JLabel` or `JPanel` everytime,instead u should add the `JLabel` to the `JPanel` in your constructor and in the `update` function, call `picture.setIcon(icon);` without creating a new `JLabel`.

Your constructor should look something like this :

```
public PageReader()
{
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    picture=new JLabel();
    JPanel anzeige = new JPanel();
    anzeige.add(picture, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    setContentPane(anzeige);


    pack();
    setResizable(false);
    setVisible(true);
}
```

The remaining part of code in your constructor should go to `update`

EDIT :

```
public void update(int pos) throws IOException
{
    urlString = "http:"+viewable[pos];

    url = new URL(urlString);
    image = ImageIO.read(url);

    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(image); 

    picture.setIcon(icon);


    int breite = icon.getImage().getWidth(this);
    int hoehe = icon.getImage().getHeight(this);


    do
    {
        if(hoehe>400)
        {
            breite *= 0.75;
            hoehe *= 0.75;
            icon.setImage(icon.getImage().getScaledInstance(breite, hoehe, image.SCALE_DEFAULT));
        }

        if(hoehe<400)
        {
            hoehe *= 1.2;
            breite *=1.2;
            icon.setImage(icon.getImage().getScaledInstance(breite, hoehe, image.SCALE_DEFAULT));
        }
    }while(hoehe>400&&hoehe<300);


    icon.setImage(icon.getImage().getScaledInstance(breite, hoehe, image.SCALE_DEFAULT));

}
```

Now in the main class, U should declare something like

```
PageReader pr=new PageReader
```

Wherever U are using `new PageReader(4)`, u should use `pr.update(4)`

@MegaCleptomaniac, I am no expert on image stuff,so I think you should listen to what @MadProgrammer says about not using `getScaledInstance`

Comment: thanks for your answer but i´m pretty new in Swing. Could you maybe tell me how to implement this change in Detail ? `public void update(int pos) throws IOException
 {
  urlString = "http:"+viewable[pos];
  
  url = new URL(urlString);
  image = ImageIO.read(url);
  
  ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(image); 
  
  picture = new JLabel();
  picture.setIcon(icon);
 }`

Comment: Thank you for your good explanation. I´ll take both, yours and MadProgrammers answers, in account to improve my current code and to finish my little project succsesfull.