# How to change images in jlable automatically

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

I am trying to display different  images in 3 different  jlables. There  is a folder with images in them. I have display the images in the jlable and the image has to change after 60 seconds. No matter  what I  try I  cannot  do it. Can somebody help me.

Comment: @MadProgrammer There is no jTable in this question.

Comment: @zilk It read as jtable on my phone :P

Comment: Simple make a Swing `Timer` (see [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for more details) and update the label each time it ticks

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is, use a Swing `Timer`, it allows you to schedule a callback in the future, which is delivered within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread, making it safe to update the UI from, for example...

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private JLabel label;
        private File[] images;
        private int imageIndex;

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            label = new JLabel();
            label.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
            label.setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
            add(label);
            images = new File("...").listFiles();
            imageIndex = -1;
            nextImage();
            Timer timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    nextImage();
                }
            });
            timer.start();
        }

        protected void nextImage() {
            if (images.length > 0) {
                imageIndex++;
                if (imageIndex >= images.length) {
                    imageIndex = 0;
                }
                try {
                    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(images[imageIndex]);
                    label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(image));
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(400, 400);
        }

    }

}
```

Have a look at [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for more details.

If your images are large or are coming from a slow service (like over the internet), you might consider using a `SwingWorker` instead, this allows you to perform long running or blocking operations in the background (off the EDT), but which are easier to synchronise updates back to the EDT with.  Have a look at [Refresh Image in JLabel with Timer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31066606/refresh-image-in-jlabel-with-timer/31067017#31067017) for more details