# Scale JPanel's graphics object and save it to a BufferedImage - Java

Tags: java, swing

I have managed to save a print of the JPanel to a BufferedImage with ScreenImage class,which just use the function:

```
Panel.paint(Graphics g)
```

My problem is that I need to perform the scale on the BufferedImage, so I lose quality. If I do the scale on the graphics object I don't lose quality. Here is my code so far:

```
private void drawReflex(){

 BufferedImage firstimg = new BufferedImage(getWidth() , getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR);
 Graphics2D g1 = firstimg.createGraphics();
 this.paint(g1); // this method is inside a class which extends JPanel
}

    @Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);

    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2.scale(3,3);
    drawReflex();
    g2.scale(1,1);

}
```

Unfortunately I don't get any scale with the above code. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're not drawing to the component's `Graphics` object?  You should also use `print` or `printAll` to take a snapshot of the component, but you probably shouldn't do it from within one of the component's paint methods.  You should also call `Graphics#dispose` on the `Graphics` contexts your create otherwise you could leak resources

Comment: `g1` and `g3` are unaffected by the settings `g` and, without further evidence, you are likely to cause a `StackOverflowException`

Comment: You also might find something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14115950/quality-of-image-after-resize-very-low-java/14116752#14116752) of some help

Comment: I paint the graphics of of JPanel to g1 with the command  this.paint(g1)

Comment: Your objective is a little unclear, so it's difficult to know what to suggest in order to achieve it. Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem and some details about what you want to achieve and why your current efforts have failed to achieve it. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: I simplified the code. Do you know how to get a scaled instance of a graphics object?

Comment: As you can see, you simplified code has generated some confusion. As to you question, do I know how to scale `Graphics`, yes

Comment: My question is simple: How to get a scaled instance of a graphics object and print it to a BufferedImage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scaling will also generate some level or artifacts, generally speaking one step scaling is bad idea and even at the simplest of solutions, you should try and perform a factor of 2 scaling operation, stepping up/down to your desired target, something which is demonstrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14115950/quality-of-image-after-resize-very-low-java/14116752#14116752), you might even consider using something like [imgscalr](https://github.com/thebuzzmedia/imgscalr) instead

The following example provides you with the ability to scale a `Graphics` context from 10% up to 300% through the use of a `JSlider`.

I simply generates `BufferedImage` at the desired scaled sized (based on the current size of the component), scales the `Graphics` context and then uses `printAll` to generate a snapshot.  It then saves the resulting image in the current directly using the "scale" as part of the name

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSlider;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;


public class ScalingTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ScalingTest();
    }

    public ScalingTest() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                ImagePane pane = new ImagePane();
                JButton btn = new JButton("Scale");
                JSlider slider = new JSlider(10, 300);
                slider.setMinorTickSpacing(5);
                slider.setMajorTickSpacing(10);
                slider.setSnapToTicks(true);
                btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        try {
                            float scale = slider.getValue() / 100f;
                            Dimension size = pane.getSize();
                            System.out.println("Original = " + size);
                            size.width *= scale;
                            size.height *= scale;
                            System.out.println("Scaled = " + size);
                            BufferedImage scaled = new BufferedImage(size.width, size.height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
                            Graphics2D g2d = scaled.createGraphics();
                            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ALPHA_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_ALPHA_INTERPOLATION_QUALITY);
                            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
                            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_COLOR_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_COLOR_RENDER_QUALITY);
                            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_DITHERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_DITHER_ENABLE);
                            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_FRACTIONALMETRICS, RenderingHints.VALUE_FRACTIONALMETRICS_ON);
                            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
                            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
                            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_STROKE_CONTROL, RenderingHints.VALUE_STROKE_PURE);
                            g2d.scale(scale, scale);
                            pane.printAll(g2d);
                            g2d.dispose();

                            ImageIO.write(scaled, "png", new File("Scaledx" + scale + ".png"));
                        } catch (IOException ex) {
                            ex.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });
                JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 1));
                panel.add(slider);
                panel.add(btn);

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(pane);
                frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class ImagePane extends JPanel {

        private BufferedImage bg;

        public ImagePane() {
            try {
                bg = ImageIO.read(new File("/Volumes/Disk02/Dropbox/MegaTokyo/issue194.jpg"));
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return bg == null ? new Dimension(200, 200) : new Dimension(bg.getWidth(), bg.getHeight());
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            int x = (getWidth() - bg.getWidth()) / 2;
            int y = (getHeight() - bg.getHeight()) / 2;
            g2d.drawImage(bg, x, y, this);
            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }

}
```

Personally, I'd grab the shap shot at a scale of 1:1 and scaling the resulting image as I think you'll still get a better result, but that's me. You might find [The Perils of Image.getScaledInstance()](https://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/04/03/perils-of-image-getscaledinstance.html) of interest as to why scaling a `BufferedImage` doesn't always return a decent result

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This code shows how to scale a bufferedImage. It's not what I am asking. I want to know how to get a scaled instance of a JPanel's graphics object and paint it to a bufferedImage.

Comment: Actually, it worked fine! Thank you very much. I will accept your answer.

Comment: Just beware, Java's scaling is optimised towards speed, so quality is never going to be as good as if you used a library or used a stepped algorithm