# Smooth Scaling of Image in Swing

Tags: java, image, swing

I created a method to resize the image from project resource package which holds the images and icons I use. However, it doesn't seem to render it or resize it smoothly.

```
public Image getResourceImage(String filepath){
        Image img = new ImageIcon(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(filepath)).getImage();
        return img;
        /* Example usage: 
            Image loginBg = new ImageMethod().getAssetImage("foldername/filename.extension");
        */
    }
```

Below are the original png images.

[image] [image]

And below are the resized version which I'm using for the login panel.

[image]

It looks pixelated. Is there any way to achieve something as clear and smooth like this considering the original icon dimensions is 512x512

[image]

The icons are all in PNG format.

I've limited knowledge with Images in Java so I'd appreciate any help or suggestion.

Thanks.

I've finally solved it. Created 3 versions of my method.

```
public Image getResourceImage(String filepath){
        Image img = new ImageIcon(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(filepath)).getImage();
        return img;
        /* Example usage: 
            Image loginBg = new ImageMethod().getAssetImage("foldername/filename.extension");
        */
    }

    public ImageIcon getResourceImage(String filepath, JLabel label){
        Image rawImage = new ImageIcon(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(filepath)).getImage();
        Image renderedImage = rawImage.getScaledInstance(label.getWidth(), label.getHeight(), Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
        ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(renderedImage);
        return image;

    }

    public Image getResourceImage(String filepath, JPanel panel){
        Image rawImage = new ImageIcon(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(filepath)).getImage();
        Image renderedImage = rawImage.getScaledInstance(panel.getWidth(), panel.getHeight(), Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
        return renderedImage;

    }
```

This will definitely help the others. Thanks for the advice Obicere.

Comment: Have you tried manually scaling it to use a better method? [Image#getScaledInstance(int width, int height, int hints)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Image.html#getScaledInstance%28int,%20int,%20int%29)

Comment: @Obicere Thank you very much for the suggestion. It worked. I created 3 versions of my method and Image.SCALE_SMOOTH did the trick. Thanks.

Comment: Start by having a look at [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14115950/quality-of-image-after-resize-very-low-java/14116752#14116752) and [The Perils of Image#getScaledInstance](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/04/03/perils-of-image-getscaledinstance.html)