# (Game Design) Antialiasing in Java Graphics2d

Tags: java, game-development, graphics2d

I want to antialiase an image with shape (plane) I draw in it. I draw the plane image in Adobe AI and put them in my resource folder. The image looks like below.

[image]

When I use this line of code
`g2.drawImage(image, (int)x, (int)y, width, height, null);`
to draw it on the screen, the edge becomes edgy.
[image]

I know there is a way to antialiase a g2d shape using renderingHints, but I am not sure if it worls on shape in the image...

So, any help is appreciated!

Full Code below:

```
package entity;

import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import main.Game;
import main.GamePanel;

// Module HP
// Acceleration and speed
public class Player extends Plane{
    
    private BufferedImage basic;
    // acceleration vector lists
    private final ArrayList<double[]> accelerations;
    
    // rate of increasing speed
    // 1.0 / (time to reach max speed in seconds) * FPS
    private final double ACCCONST = 1.0/(0.5*Game.FPS);
    // special attributes
    
    //TEMP
    private final ArrayList<Bullet> bullets;
    
    public Player(GamePanel gp) {
        this.loadImages();
        this.gp = gp;
        // set image
        image = basic;
        // basic attributes
        x = Game.SPAWNX - width/2;
        y = Game.SPAWNY - height;
        // init lists
        accelerations = new ArrayList<>();
        
        //TEMP
        bullets = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    private void loadImages() {
        try {
            basic = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/res/players/basic.png"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    // setters
    public void addAcceleration(double[] pair) {
        if (pair.length == 2) {
            accelerations.add(pair);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void setEnginePower(double enginePower) {
        this.enginePower = enginePower;
        this.maxSpeed = enginePower;
    }
    @Override
    public void setAtkSpeed(double atkSpeed) {
        this.atkSpeed = atkSpeed;
        if (atkSpeed == 0) atkInterval = (int)Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
        else atkInterval = (int)(Game.FPS/atkSpeed);
    }
    // getters
    
    // get movement info
    private double[] getRAcceleration() {
        // get resultant acceleration
        xAPF = 0; yAPF = 0;
        for (double[] pair: accelerations) {
            if (pair.length == 2) {
                xAPF += pair[0];
                yAPF += pair[1];
            }
        }
        accelerations.clear();
        return new double[]{xAPF, yAPF};
    }
    private void move() {
        double[] pair = this.getRAcceleration();
        // no acceleration
        if (pair[0] == 0 && pair[1] == 0) {
            // reset speed to 0
            if (xSPF > 0) xSPF = Math.max(xSPF - Game.DECELERATION, 0);
            else if (xSPF < 0) xSPF = Math.min(xSPF + Game.DECELERATION, 0);
            if (ySPF > 0) ySPF = Math.max(ySPF - Game.DECELERATION, 0);
            else if (ySPF < 0) ySPF = Math.min(ySPF + Game.DECELERATION, 0);
        }
        // accleration exists
        else {
            // max speed = acceleration
            if (xAPF > 0) xSPF = Math.min(xSPF + xAPF*ACCCONST, maxSpeed);
            else xSPF = Math.max(xSPF + xAPF*ACCCONST, -maxSpeed);
            if (yAPF > 0) ySPF = Math.min(ySPF + yAPF*ACCCONST, maxSpeed);
            else ySPF = Math.max(ySPF + yAPF*ACCCONST, -maxSpeed);
        }
        // move
        x += xSPF;
        y += ySPF;
    }
    private void shoot() {
        double spawnX = x + singleShootingScale * width;
        double spawnY = y;
        Bullet bullet = new Bullet(gp, this, spawnX, spawnY);
        bullet.addAcceleration(new double[]{0, -10});
        bullets.add(bullet);
    }
    private void getAFromKey() {
        boolean[] keyPressed = gp.keyH.keyPressed;
        if (keyPressed[0]) accelerations.add(new double[]{0, -enginePower / Game.FPS});
        if (keyPressed[1]) accelerations.add(new double[]{-enginePower / Game.FPS, 0});
        if (keyPressed[2]) accelerations.add(new double[]{0, enginePower / Game.FPS});
        if (keyPressed[3]) accelerations.add(new double[]{enginePower / Game.FPS, 0});
    }
    
    @Override
    public void update() {
        // check all events
        
        //TEMP
        for (Bullet bullet: bullets) bullet.update();
        
        // shoot
        if (atkInterval == 0) this.shoot();
        else if (frameCnt % atkInterval == 0) this.shoot();
        
        this.getAFromKey();
        this.move();
        
        frameCnt += 1;
    }
    @Override
    public void draw(Graphics2D g2) {
        
        //TEMP
        for (Bullet bullet: bullets) bullet.draw(g2);
        
        g2.drawImage(image, (int)x, (int)y, width, height, null);
    }
    
}
```

I have reviewed some past posts about this kind of problems but I did not find one that suits me [shape in image].

If there is no way to do it on java, perhaps it's the way I draw my art? (What's a better way to put art in Java game design)

Comment: Both `Graphics#drawImage` or `Image#getScaledInstance` focus on speed over quality.  You could "fake" the antialiase in some case by scaling the out by 4 (ie if your target output is 1080p, draw your original output at 4x that and then scale it down).  Alternatively, don't scale you images if you don't have, instead, have your art at the desired output size to start with or use better scaling approaches for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14115950/quality-of-image-after-resize-very-low-java/14116752#14116752)

Comment: If you are going to scale your assets, it might be better to keep a reference to the scaled object rather then scaling them on each paint pass, this may help improve the performance

Comment: If you can use vector graphics, SVG for example, you can scale much more freely.

Comment: Thank for the help guys, I like the idea of faking antialiase by @MadProgrammer. Also, the optimization on performance is quite good!

Comment: Drawing shapes uses RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, but I believe image scaling uses RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING.  I probably would pre-scale the image as much as possible instead, though.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, redraw the image. I did something similar here.
The key line is  `Image scaledImg = img.getScaledInstance(scaleImage[0], scaleImage[1], Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);`

```
 private static int[] scaleImage(int originalWidth, int originalHeight) {
    int newWidth;
    int newHeight;

    // Calculate new dimensions while preserving aspect ratio
    if (originalWidth > originalHeight) {
        // Landscape orientation
        newWidth = 200;
        newHeight = (int) ((double) originalHeight / originalWidth * 200);
    } else {
        // Portrait or square orientation
        newHeight = 200;
        newWidth = (int) ((double) originalWidth / originalHeight * 200);
    }

    return new int[]{newWidth, newHeight};
}

private JButton createImageButton(String imagePath) {
    JButton button = new JButton();
    String description = "";

    try {
        int startIndex = imagePath.lastIndexOf("/") + 1;
        int endIndex = imagePath.lastIndexOf(".");
        BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File(imagePath));

        int[] scaleImage = scaleImage(img.getWidth(), img.getHeight());

        Image scaledImg = img.getScaledInstance(scaleImage[0], scaleImage[1], Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(scaledImg);

        if (startIndex < 0 || endIndex < 0 || startIndex >= endIndex) {
            // Handle invalid path or file extension not found
            description = imagePath;
        }
        button.setIcon(icon);
        description = imagePath.substring(startIndex, endIndex);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        if (V2RApp.DEBUG) {
            System.err.println("Error loading image: " + imagePath + e.getMessage());
        }
    } finally {
        button.setVerticalTextPosition(SwingConstants.BOTTOM);
        button.setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        button.setText("<html><center>" + description + "</center></html>");
        button.setToolTipText(description);
    }

    return button;
}
```

Comment: You should have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14115950/quality-of-image-after-resize-very-low-java/14116752#14116752) for reasons why I wouldn't recommend using `Image#getScaledInstance` and especially not over a single range.  FYI, you can also pass `-1` to either the `width` or `height` parameter and it will maintain the aspect ratio.  Since the OP is just scaling it by 0.5, it's probably not a "massive" issue, but personally I'd make use of a different approach, one which makes use of `RenderingHints`, so I'd have more control over the result, but that's me

Comment: I needed to scale down very low palette images, so jagged-ness wasn't a problem and this was simple. But none the less, the idea of creating a new Image is the same. But yes using rendering hints is a good idea, I've just never seen it used before.