# Same Java Fonts Slightly Different in Eclipse vs JNLP

Tags: java, eclipse, fonts, jnlp

First of all, I don't really have any code, because it's a universal problem I'm seeing and am just wondering if anyone else has ever encountered it.

As near as I can tell the eclipse and JNLP UI properties are identical...So, what I am seeing is that when assigning the exact same component - any component - the exact same font (I'm using Arial, Bold, 12 for everything) and the results in JNLP and Eclipse are slightly different, even when run on the exact same computer.

Here's a screenshot (Eclipse result is on top, JNLP result is on bottom):

[image]

Anyhoo, if anyone has ever seen this or has any suggestions, that would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is most probably the properties used by the JRE for text antialiasing.  Visit [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5998015/418556) to experiment.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the tip!  So, my eclipse was going against JDK 1.6.0_24, and my JNLP was going against JRE 1.6.0_24 and producing the above results.

When changing my Eclipse to use the same JRE as JNLP was using, it gets the same results as JNLP...OK, so we know what the problem is!

Now then, how can I get the JRE to render exactly like the JDK?  Both being version 1.6.0_24...

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Comment: And if anyone cares, the follow-up question is here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12220002/java-jre-is-rendering-fonts-differently-than-java-jdk-both-same-version