# Java JRE is rendering fonts differently than Java JDK, both same version

Tags: fonts, java

This is related to: [Same Java Fonts Slightly Different in Eclipse vs JNLP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12219104/same-java-fonts-slightly-different-in-eclipse-vs-jnlp)

When I run my application through JDK 1.6.0_24 the fonts render in a particular way that I really like.  However, when I run my application through JRE 1.6.0_24, they render in a way that I don't like.

Here's the difference: (JDK render on top, JRE render on bottom)
[image]

So, how I can make the JRE render fonts the same way as the JDK?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Same Java Fonts Slightly Different in Eclipse vs JNLP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12219104/same-java-fonts-slightly-different-in-eclipse-vs-jnlp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I'm thinking this might be a "bug" in some versions of Java 6.  I just updated to Java 6 Update 35 and both the JDK and JRE render fonts correctly and as I would expect.  So there you have it.