# How much memory will java.awt.Image consume if JPEG is 10MB?

Tags: java, image, soap, awt, cxf

MTOM is usually used to transfer image data over SOAP (attachments). The image is mapped to a java.awt.Image (at least with CXF). Does the Image object consume a lot more memory than the actual image transferred? Let's say a transferred JPEG is 10MB, how much more space will the Image object consume?

- UPDATE -
  I'm not so sure it has anything to do with java.awt.Image at all. Focusing on CXF/MTOM more at the moment: http://cxf.547215.n5.nabble.com/MTOM-large-attachments-eating-up-JVM-heap-td5714196.html

Comment: It's most likely that the Java Image is uncompressed. But it also depends, as `java.awt.Image` can be unbuffered, meaning that until it's actually required, it may not be loaded (but in your case I doubt that's the case). The other problem is, `java.awt.Image` is an abstract class, so unless you know what the implementation is doing, it's difficult to say either way

Comment: @MadProgrammer, it's a buffered image: BufferedImage@5c799c7a: type = 5 ColorModel: #pixelBits = 24 numComponents = 3 color space = java.awt.color.ICC_ColorSpace@49a695dc transparency = 1 has alpha = false isAlphaPre = false ByteInterleavedRaster: width = 8268 height = 5839 #numDataElements 3 dataOff[0] = 2

Comment: You can't depend on the implementation, but the original statement stands. It's likely that the image data is uncompressed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does the Image object consume a lot more memory than the actual image transferred?

Typically yes. The idea of most of the file formats is to compress image data.

> Let's say a transferred JPEG is 10MB, how much more space will the Image object consume?

The RAM size depends on W * H * 'pixel depth'.  E.G. RGBA in 256 shades is 4 bytes per pixel.  JPEG does not support alpha transparency, so it would be 3 bytes per pixel.

---

For some idea of the effectiveness of JPEG compression efficiency at different levels, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5998015/418556):

[image]

Comment: ... and I don't believe there is a direct relationship between jpeg file size and those dimensions.  (Doesn't jpeg use lossy compression?)

Comment: @StephenC  I think the answer linked in the edit should clarify a few things.  And yes, definitely lossy.  The 3rd image above at 80% quality(/20% compression) is the JPEG.  It is not as crisp as the first two images, yet still larger in bytes than the PNG (2nd image).