# Image Resizing in Java to reduce image size

Tags: java, image-processing

I have an Image of say dimensions 800x800 which has a size of 170 kb. I want to resize this image to say 600x600. After resizing i want the image size to be reduced. How can i do this?

Comment: You could take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11959758/java-maintaining-aspect-ratio-of-jpanel-background-image/11959928#11959928

Comment: 1) *"After resizing i want the image size to be reduced."* When held in memory, or serialized to PNG, JPG or GIF?  The 1st will result in a reduction in bytes, the 2nd often won't.  2) What format is the image? (PNG, GIF, JPEG..)

Comment: If the format is JPEG, it will most likely be more effective to reduce image byte size on disk by increasing the compression ratio. See [`ImageCompressionDemo`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5998015/418556) for example source.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You don't need a full blown Image processing library for simply resizing an image.

The recommended approach is by using **progressive bilinear scaling**, like so (feel free to use this method as is in your code):

```
public BufferedImage scale(BufferedImage img, int targetWidth, int targetHeight) {

    int type = (img.getTransparency() == Transparency.OPAQUE) ? BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB : BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB;
    BufferedImage ret = img;
    BufferedImage scratchImage = null;
    Graphics2D g2 = null;

    int w = img.getWidth();
    int h = img.getHeight();

    int prevW = w;
    int prevH = h;

    do {
        if (w > targetWidth) {
            w /= 2;
            w = (w < targetWidth) ? targetWidth : w;
        }

        if (h > targetHeight) {
            h /= 2;
            h = (h < targetHeight) ? targetHeight : h;
        }

        if (scratchImage == null) {
            scratchImage = new BufferedImage(w, h, type);
            g2 = scratchImage.createGraphics();
        }

        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
        g2.drawImage(ret, 0, 0, w, h, 0, 0, prevW, prevH, null);

        prevW = w;
        prevH = h;
        ret = scratchImage;
    } while (w != targetWidth || h != targetHeight);

    if (g2 != null) {
        g2.dispose();
    }

    if (targetWidth != ret.getWidth() || targetHeight != ret.getHeight()) {
        scratchImage = new BufferedImage(targetWidth, targetHeight, type);
        g2 = scratchImage.createGraphics();
        g2.drawImage(ret, 0, 0, null);
        g2.dispose();
        ret = scratchImage;
    }

    return ret;

}
```

Code modified and cleaned from the original at [Filthy Rich Clients](http://filthyrichclients.org).

---

Based on your comment, you can reduce quality and encode JPEG bytes like so:

`image` is the BufferedImage.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ImageWriter writer = (ImageWriter) ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("jpeg").next();

ImageWriteParam param = writer.getDefaultWriteParam();
param.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT);
param.setCompressionQuality(0.2f); // Change this, float between 0.0 and 1.0

writer.setOutput(ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(os));
writer.write(null, new IIOImage(image, null, null), param);
writer.dispose();
```

Now, since `os` is a `ByteArrayOutputStream`, you can Base64 encode it.

```
String base64 = Base64.encode(os.toByteArray());
```

Comment: I want to reduce image size (in bytes) after resizing it so that i can send it over a socket. The dataoutputstream says that the encoded string(Base64) is too large.

Comment: Base64 encode JPEG bytes instead. You can use `ImageIO` for this.

Comment: Genius, this worked, and now I realize I don't even need Scalr, thanks. But what really did the trick was using .jpg format and not .png

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why not use a library when you already have it ? I mean why did you go with using custom code ?

Comment: Gracias, te amo

Answer (score 7):

You could use the 100% Java, Apache2 open source [imgscalr library](https://github.com/rkalla/imgscalr) (a single static class) and do something like this:

```
import org.imgscalr.Scalr.*; // static imports are awesome with the lib

... some class code ...

// This is a super-contrived method name, I just wanted to incorporate
// the details from your question accurately.
public static void resizeImageTo600x600(BufferedImage image) {
    ImageIO.write(resize(image, 600), "JPG", new File("/path/to/file.jpg"));
}
```

**NOTE**: If the above looks odd, the static import allows me to use the *resize* call directly without specifying *Scalr.resize(...)*

Additionally, if the quality of the scaled image written out doesn't look good enough (it will be written out quickly though) you can use more arguments to the *resize* method like so:

```
public static void resizeImageTo600x600(BufferedImage image) {
    ImageIO.write(resize(image, Method.ULTRA_QUALITY, 600), "JPG", new File("/path/to/file.jpg"));
}
```

.. and you can even apply a BufferedImageOp to the result to soften it incase the downscaling makes the image look to jaggy:

```
public static void resizeImageTo600x600(BufferedImage image) {
    ImageIO.write(resize(image, Method.ULTRA_QUALITY, 600, Scalr.OP_ANTIALIAS), "JPG", new File("/path/to/file.jpg"));
}
```

You can start playing around with the library by just adding the following dep entry in your Maven POM (imgscalr is in the Maven central repo):

```
<dependency> 
  <groupId>org.imgscalr</groupId>
  <artifactId>imgscalr-lib</artifactId>
  <version>4.2</version>
  <type>jar</type>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I don't understand the license. Can I use this in a personal website?

Comment: Also what if the image is smaller, will it scale up?

Comment: The link is broken and leads to a malicious site.

Comment: @yurin thank you for the heads up - fixed!

Answer (score 3):

Use some good framework which supports Image Processing through Java  e.g. [IamageJ](http://rsbweb.nih.gov/ij/features.html)

There is also some basic support available in Java through some classes such as [MemoryImageSource](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/awt/image/MemoryImageSource.html) and [PixelGrabber](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/awt/image/PixelGrabber.html).

Comment: I checked it out. I want to do this in my Java program!

Comment: I updated the answer with Basic Support information in Core Java. Hope that helps.