# Reducing the size of byte array without losing the data

Tags: java, compression, jpeg

I have a byte array of a JPEG photo created as below.

```
        import java.sql.Blob;

        byte[] blobAsBytes = null;
        blobLength = (int) blob.length();
        blobAsBytes = blob.getBytes(1, blobLength);
        //Some operation to make the byte array size 20kb
        return blobAsBytes;
```

I need to return this byte array to a service which accepts Oracle long raw type and it works fine.

As this needs to be transferred through network, byte array returned by method has to be less than 20kb.

How can I make the byte array small in size, and send without any data loss, so it can be restored as a photo?

Comment: If usual compression algorithms don't work (likely to happen as most image formats are already compressed) you are out of luck. You can't work against information theory.

Comment: Could it be possible to make it to buffered image then reduce size and try converting back to byte array ?

Comment: Sure, if you are allowed to make the image smaller, its encoding is also smaller. But this would definitely change the image.

Comment: What image format is being used for the source `blob`?

Comment: It has to be 'jpg'. But is it possible to achieve this with any format (just to know) ?

Comment: This thread helped me to get this done. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12879540/image-resizing-in-java-to-reduce-image-size