# Resizing an image in java

Tags: java, image, resize

I have an java application allows user to take a photo from his camera and send it to me using a web service, But my problem is while sending the image. The send progress takes long time because image is big so i want to compress image. I have tried to:

1- Use this code:

```
Bitmap img = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("C:\\test.jpg");

ByteArrayOutputStream streem = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
img.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 75, streem);
byte[] b = streem.toByteArray();
```

But this code is useless in my case because it make image very bad and dosent affect on image size a lot.

2- Search a lot about ways to resize but all results is using BufferedImage. I cant use this type(Class) because it takes a lot of memory size:

```
private static BufferedImage resizeImage(BufferedImage originalImage, int type)
{
    BufferedImage resizedImage = new BufferedImage(new_w, new_h, type);
    Graphics2D g = resizedImage.createGraphics();
    g.drawImage(originalImage, 0, 0, new_w, new_h, null);
    g.dispose();

    return resizedImage;
}
```

I want to use Bitmap instead, Any body can help me in my application???

Comment: Experiment with a higher level of JPEG compression.  See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5995798/java-text-on-image/5998015#5998015) for code to experiment with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`ImageIO`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/package-summary.html) to write the `BufferedImage` to the format you need

You can supply a output stream to `ImageIO`so you should be able to write to just about anywhere.

Check out [Writing/Saving an Image](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/saveimage.html) for more details

Answer (score 1):

I have found these tow method:

```
private static int CalculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options,
        int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    float height = (float) options.outHeight;
    float width = (float) options.outWidth;
    float inSampleSize = 0;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {
        inSampleSize = width > height ? height / reqHeight : width
                / reqWidth;
    }

    return (int) Math.round(inSampleSize);
}

public static byte[] ResizeImage(int reqWidth, int reqHeight, byte[] buffer) {
    BitmapFactory.Options op = new Options();
    op.inJustDecodeBounds = true;

    BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(buffer, 0, buffer.length, op);

    op.inSampleSize = CalculateInSampleSize(op, reqWidth, reqHeight);

    op.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    try {
        return ToByte(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(buffer, 0,
                buffer.length, op));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }

}
```