# Changing .png to work with JpegImagesToMovie.java

Tags: java, image, png, jpeg

I am using the JpegImagesToMovie.java to convert images to a .mov file. I was wondering if there was anyway I could edit this to work with .png files as the quality of the video is not very good and changing it would improve it.

```
ImageIO.write(img, "png", new File("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\tmp\\" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png"));

ImageIO.write(img, "jpeg", new File("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\tmp\\" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png"));

ImageIO.write(img, "png", new File("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\tmp\\" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpeg"));
```

All three of those would produce a video (no errors through the program) but the video wouldn't play the images just open and finish.

I also tried editing the JpegImagesToMovie.java

```
if (!filePath.toLowerCase().endsWith(".png") && !filePath.toLowerCase().endsWith(".png")) {
    continue;
```

But that didn't work, and I can't find anywhere else to edit. How can I get this to work with .png images?

Latest Update:

Here is my updated JpegImagesToMovies class

package maple;

```
/*
 * @(#)JpegImagesToMovie.java   1.3 01/03/13
 *
 * Copyright (c) 1999-2001 Sun Microsystems, Inc. All Rights Reserved.
 *
 * Sun grants you ("Licensee") a non-exclusive, royalty free, license to use,
 * modify and redistribute this software in source and binary code form,
 * provided that i) this copyright notice and license appear on all copies of
 * the software; and ii) Licensee does not utilize the software in a manner
 * which is disparaging to Sun.
 *
 * This software is provided "AS IS," without a warranty of any kind. ALL
 * EXPRESS OR IMPLIED CONDITIONS, REPRESENTATIONS AND WARRANTIES, INCLUDING ANY
 * IMPLIED WARRANTY OF MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE OR
 * NON-INFRINGEMENT, ARE HEREBY EXCLUDED. SUN AND ITS LICENSORS SHALL NOT BE
 * LIABLE FOR ANY DAMAGES SUFFERED BY LICENSEE AS A RESULT OF USING, MODIFYING
 * OR DISTRIBUTING THE SOFTWARE OR ITS DERIVATIVES. IN NO EVENT WILL SUN OR ITS
 * LICENSORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY LOST REVENUE, PROFIT OR DATA, OR FOR DIRECT,
 * INDIRECT, SPECIAL, CONSEQUENTIAL, INCIDENTAL OR PUNITIVE DAMAGES, HOWEVER
 * CAUSED AND REGARDLESS OF THE THEORY OF LIABILITY, ARISING OUT OF THE USE OF
 * OR INABILITY TO USE SOFTWARE, EVEN IF SUN HAS BEEN ADVISED OF THE
 * POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGES.
 *
 * This software is not designed or intended for use in on-line control of
 * aircraft, air traffic, aircraft navigation or aircraft communications; or in
 * the design, construction, operation or maintenance of any nuclear
 * facility. Licensee represents and warrants that it will not use or
 * redistribute the Software for such purposes.
 */

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.media.*;
import javax.media.control.*;
import javax.media.protocol.*;
import javax.media.datasink.*;
import javax.media.format.RGBFormat;
import javax.media.format.VideoFormat;

/**
 * This program takes a list of JPEG image files and convert them into a
 * QuickTime movie.
 */
public class JpegImagesToMovie implements ControllerListener, DataSinkListener {

        static private Vector<String> getImageFilesPathsVector(
                        String imagesFolderPath) {
                File imagesFolder = new File(imagesFolderPath);
                String[] imageFilesArray = imagesFolder.list();
                Vector<String> imageFilesPathsVector = new Vector<String>();
                for (String imageFileName : imageFilesArray) {
                        if (!imageFileName.toLowerCase().endsWith("png"))
                                continue;
                        imageFilesPathsVector.add(imagesFolder.getAbsolutePath()
                                        + File.separator + imageFileName);
                }
                return imageFilesPathsVector;
        }

        public boolean doIt(int width, int height, int frameRate,
                        Vector<String> inFiles, MediaLocator outML) {
                ImageDataSource ids = new ImageDataSource(width, height, frameRate,
                                inFiles);

                Processor p;

                try {
                        System.err
                                        .println("- create processor for the image datasource ...");
                        p = Manager.createProcessor(ids);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                        System.err
                                        .println("Yikes!  Cannot create a processor from the data source.");
                        return false;
                }

                p.addControllerListener(this);

                // Put the Processor into configured state so we can set
                // some processing options on the processor.
                p.configure();
                if (!waitForState(p, Processor.Configured)) {
                        System.err.println("Failed to configure the processor.");
                        return false;
                }

                // Set the output content descriptor to QuickTime.
                p.setContentDescriptor(new ContentDescriptor(
                                FileTypeDescriptor.QUICKTIME));// FileTypeDescriptor.MSVIDEO

                // Query for the processor for supported formats.
                // Then set it on the processor.
                TrackControl tcs[] = p.getTrackControls();
                Format f[] = tcs[0].getSupportedFormats();
                if (f == null || f.length <= 0) {
                        System.err.println("The mux does not support the input format: "
                                        + tcs[0].getFormat());
                        return false;
                }

                tcs[0].setFormat(f[0]);

                System.err.println("Setting the track format to: " + f[0]);

                // We are done with programming the processor. Let's just
                // realize it.
                p.realize();
                if (!waitForState(p, Controller.Realized)) {
                        System.err.println("Failed to realize the processor.");
                        return false;
                }

                // Now, we'll need to create a DataSink.
                DataSink dsink;
                if ((dsink = createDataSink(p, outML)) == null) {
                        System.err
                                        .println("Failed to create a DataSink for the given output MediaLocator: "
                                                        + outML);
                        return false;
                }

                dsink.addDataSinkListener(this);
                fileDone = false;

                System.err.println("start processing...");

                // OK, we can now start the actual transcoding.
                try {
                        p.start();
                        dsink.start();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                        System.err.println("IO error during processing");
                        return false;
                }

                // Wait for EndOfStream event.
                waitForFileDone();

                // Cleanup.
                try {
                        dsink.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
                p.removeControllerListener(this);

                System.err.println("...done processing.");

                return true;
        }

        /**
         * Create the DataSink.
         */
        DataSink createDataSink(Processor p, MediaLocator outML) {

                DataSource ds;

                if ((ds = p.getDataOutput()) == null) {
                        System.err
                                        .println("Something is really wrong: the processor does not have an output DataSource");
                        return null;
                }

                DataSink dsink;

                try {
                        System.err.println("- create DataSink for: " + outML);
                        dsink = Manager.createDataSink(ds, outML);
                        dsink.open();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                        System.err.println("Cannot create the DataSink: " + e);
                        return null;
                }

                return dsink;
        }

        Object waitSync = new Object();
        boolean stateTransitionOK = true;

        /**
         * Block until the processor has transitioned to the given state. Return
         * false if the transition failed.
         */
        boolean waitForState(Processor p, int state) {
                synchronized (waitSync) {
                        try {
                                while (p.getState() < state && stateTransitionOK)
                                        waitSync.wait();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                        }
                }
                return stateTransitionOK;
        }

        /**
         * Controller Listener.
         */
        public void controllerUpdate(ControllerEvent evt) {

                if (evt instanceof ConfigureCompleteEvent
                                || evt instanceof RealizeCompleteEvent
                                || evt instanceof PrefetchCompleteEvent) {
                        synchronized (waitSync) {
                                stateTransitionOK = true;
                                waitSync.notifyAll();
                        }
                } else if (evt instanceof ResourceUnavailableEvent) {
                        synchronized (waitSync) {
                                stateTransitionOK = false;
                                waitSync.notifyAll();
                        }
                } else if (evt instanceof EndOfMediaEvent) {
                        evt.getSourceController().stop();
                        evt.getSourceController().close();
                }
        }

        Object waitFileSync = new Object();
        boolean fileDone = false;
        boolean fileSuccess = true;

        /**
         * Block until file writing is done.
         */
        boolean waitForFileDone() {
                synchronized (waitFileSync) {
                        try {
                                while (!fileDone)
                                        waitFileSync.wait();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                        }
                }
                return fileSuccess;
        }

        /**
         * Event handler for the file writer.
         */
        public void dataSinkUpdate(DataSinkEvent evt) {

                if (evt instanceof EndOfStreamEvent) {
                        synchronized (waitFileSync) {
                                fileDone = true;
                                waitFileSync.notifyAll();
                        }
                } else if (evt instanceof DataSinkErrorEvent) {
                        synchronized (waitFileSync) {
                                fileDone = true;
                                fileSuccess = false;
                                waitFileSync.notifyAll();
                        }
                }
        }

        public static void main(String args[]) {
                // changed this method a bit

                if (args.length == 0)
                        prUsage();

                // Parse the arguments.
                int i = 0;
                int width = -1, height = -1, frameRate = -1;
                Vector<String> inputFiles = new Vector<String>();
                String rootDir = null;
                String outputURL = null;

                while (i < args.length) {

                        if (args[i].equals("-w")) {
                                i++;
                                if (i >= args.length)
                                        prUsage();
                                width = new Integer(args[i]).intValue();
                        } else if (args[i].equals("-h")) {
                                i++;
                                if (i >= args.length)
                                        prUsage();
                                height = new Integer(args[i]).intValue();
                        } else if (args[i].equals("-f")) {
                                i++;
                                if (i >= args.length)
                                        prUsage();
                                // new Integer(args[i]).intValue();
                                frameRate = Integer.parseInt(args[i]);

                        } else if (args[i].equals("-o")) {
                                i++;
                                if (i >= args.length)
                                        prUsage();
                                outputURL = args[i];
                        } else if (args[i].equals("-i")) {
                                i++;
                                if (i >= args.length)
                                        prUsage();
                                rootDir = args[i];

                        } else {
                                System.out.println(".");
                                prUsage();
                        }
                        i++;
                }

                if (rootDir == null) {
                        System.out
                                        .println("Since no input (-i) forder provided, assuming this JAR is inside JPEGs folder.");
                        rootDir = (new File(".")).getAbsolutePath();
                }
                inputFiles = getImageFilesPathsVector(rootDir);

                if (inputFiles.size() == 0)
                        prUsage();
                if (outputURL == null) {
                        outputURL = (new File(rootDir)).getAbsolutePath() + File.separator
                                        + "pngs2movie.mov";
                }
                if (!outputURL.toLowerCase().startsWith("file:///")) {
                        outputURL = "file:///" + outputURL;
                }

                // Check for output file extension.
                if (!outputURL.toLowerCase().endsWith(".mov")) {
                        prUsage();
                        outputURL += ".mov";
                        System.out
                                        .println("outputURL should be ending with mov. Making this happen.\nNow outputURL is: "
                                                        + outputURL);
                }

                if (width < 0 || height < 0) {
                        prUsage();
                        System.out.println("Trying to guess movie size from first image");
                        BufferedImage firstImageInFolder = getFirstImageInFolder(rootDir);
                        width = firstImageInFolder.getWidth();
                        height = firstImageInFolder.getHeight();
                        System.out.println("width = " + width);
                        System.out.println("height = " + height);
                }

                // Check the frame rate.
                if (frameRate < 1)
                        frameRate = 30;

                // Generate the output media locators.
                MediaLocator oml;

                if ((oml = createMediaLocator(outputURL)) == null) {
                        System.err.println("Cannot build media locator from: " + outputURL);
                        System.exit(0);
                }

                JpegImagesToMovie imageToMovie = new JpegImagesToMovie();
                imageToMovie.doIt(width, height, frameRate, inputFiles, oml);

                System.exit(0);
        }

        private static BufferedImage getFirstImageInFolder(String rootDir) {
                File rootFile = new File(rootDir);
                String[] list = (rootFile).list();
                BufferedImage bufferedImage = null;
                for (String filePath : list) {
                        if (!filePath.toLowerCase().endsWith(".png")
                                        && !filePath.toLowerCase().endsWith(".png")) {
                                continue;
                        }
                        try {
                                bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(new File(rootFile
                                                .getAbsoluteFile() + File.separator + filePath));
                                break;
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                }
                return bufferedImage;
        }

        static void prUsage() {
                System.err
                                .println("Usage: java JpegImagesToMovie [-w <width>] [-h <height>] [-f <frame rate>] [-o <output URL>] -i <input JPEG files dir Path>");
                // System.exit(-1);
        }

        /**
         * Create a media locator from the given string.
         */
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        public static MediaLocator createMediaLocator(String url) {

                MediaLocator ml;

                if (url.indexOf(":") > 0 && (ml = new MediaLocator(url)) != null)
                        return ml;

                if (url.startsWith(File.separator)) {
                        if ((ml = new MediaLocator("file:" + url)) != null)
                                return ml;
                } else {
                        String file = "file:" + System.getProperty("user.dir")
                                        + File.separator + url;
                        if ((ml = new MediaLocator(file)) != null)
                                return ml;
                }
                return null;
        }

        // /////////////////////////////////////////////
        //
        // Inner classes.
        // /////////////////////////////////////////////

        /**
         * A DataSource to read from a list of JPEG image files and turn that into a
         * stream of JMF buffers. The DataSource is not seekable or positionable.
         */
        class ImageDataSource extends PullBufferDataSource {

                ImageSourceStream streams[];

                ImageDataSource(int width, int height, int frameRate,
                                Vector<String> images) {
                        streams = new ImageSourceStream[1];
                        streams[0] = new PngImageSourceStream(width, height, frameRate, images);
                }

                public void setLocator(MediaLocator source) {
                }

                public MediaLocator getLocator() {
                        return null;
                }

                /**
                 * Content type is of RAW since we are sending buffers of video frames
                 * without a container format.
                 */
                public String getContentType() {
                        return ContentDescriptor.RAW;
                }

                public void connect() {
                }

                public void disconnect() {
                }

                public void start() {
                }

                public void stop() {
                }

                /**
                 * Return the ImageSourceStreams.
                 */
                public PullBufferStream[] getStreams() {
                        return streams;
                }

                /**
                 * We could have derived the duration from the number of frames and
                 * frame rate. But for the purpose of this program, it's not necessary.
                 */
                public Time getDuration() {
                        return DURATION_UNKNOWN;
                }

                public Object[] getControls() {
                        return new Object[0];
                }

                public Object getControl(String type) {
                        return null;
                }
        }

        /**
         * The source stream to go along with ImageDataSource.
         */
        class ImageSourceStream implements PullBufferStream {

                Vector<String> images;
                int width, height;
                VideoFormat format;

                int nextImage = 0; // index of the next image to be read.
                boolean ended = false;

                public ImageSourceStream(int width, int height, int frameRate,
                                Vector<String> images) {
                        this.width = width;
                        this.height = height;
                        this.images = images;

                        format = new VideoFormat(VideoFormat.JPEG, new Dimension(width,
                                        height), Format.NOT_SPECIFIED, Format.byteArray,
                                        (float) frameRate);
                }

                /**
                 * We should never need to block assuming data are read from files.
                 */
                public boolean willReadBlock() {
                        return false;
                }

                /**
                 * This is called from the Processor to read a frame worth of video
                 * data.
                 */
                public void read(Buffer buf) throws IOException {

                        // Check if we've finished all the frames.
                        if (nextImage >= images.size()) {
                                // We are done. Set EndOfMedia.
                                System.err.println("Done reading all images.");
                                buf.setEOM(true);
                                buf.setOffset(0);
                                buf.setLength(0);
                                ended = true;
                                return;
                        }

                        String imageFile = (String) images.elementAt(nextImage);
                        nextImage++;

                        System.err.println("  - reading image file: " + imageFile);

                        // Open a random access file for the next image.
                        RandomAccessFile raFile;
                        raFile = new RandomAccessFile(imageFile, "r");

                        byte data[] = null;

                        // Check the input buffer type & size.

                        if (buf.getData() instanceof byte[])
                                data = (byte[]) buf.getData();

                        // Check to see the given buffer is big enough for the frame.
                        if (data == null || data.length < raFile.length()) {
                                data = new byte[(int) raFile.length()];
                                buf.setData(data);
                        }

                        // Read the entire JPEG image from the file.
                        raFile.readFully(data, 0, (int) raFile.length());

                        System.err.println("    read " + raFile.length() + " bytes.");

                        buf.setOffset(0);
                        buf.setLength((int) raFile.length());
                        buf.setFormat(format);
                        buf.setFlags(buf.getFlags() | Buffer.FLAG_KEY_FRAME);

                        // Close the random access file.
                        raFile.close();
                }

                /**
                 * Return the format of each video frame. That will be JPEG.
                 */
                public Format getFormat() {
                        return format;
                }

                public ContentDescriptor getContentDescriptor() {
                        return new ContentDescriptor(ContentDescriptor.RAW);
                }

                public long getContentLength() {
                        return 0;
                }

                public boolean endOfStream() {
                        return ended;
                }

                public Object[] getControls() {
                        return new Object[0];
                }

                public Object getControl(String type) {
                        return null;
                }
        }

        class PngImageSourceStream extends ImageSourceStream {

              public PngImageSourceStream(int width, int height, int frameRate, Vector<String> images) {
                super(width, height, frameRate, images);

                // configure the new format as RGB format 
                format = new RGBFormat(new Dimension(width, height), Format.NOT_SPECIFIED, Format.byteArray, frameRate, 
                    24,       // 24 bits per pixel
                    1, 2, 3); // red, green and blue masks when data are in the form of byte[]
              }

              public void read(Buffer buf) throws IOException {

                // Check if we've finished all the frames.
                if (nextImage >= images.size()) {
                  // We are done. Set EndOfMedia.
                  System.err.println("Done reading all images.");
                  buf.setEOM(true);
                  buf.setOffset(0);
                  buf.setLength(0);
                  ended = true;
                  return;
                }

                String imageFile = (String) images.elementAt(nextImage);
                nextImage++;

                System.err.println("  - reading image file: " + imageFile);

                // read the PNG image
                BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read( new File(imageFile) );
                Dimension size = format.getSize();

                // convert 32-bit RGBA to 24-bit RGB
                byte[] imageData = convertTo24Bit(image.getRaster().getPixels(0, 0, size.width, size.height, (int[]) null)); 
                buf.setData(imageData);

                System.err.println("    read " + imageData.length + " bytes.");

                buf.setOffset(0);
                buf.setLength(imageData.length);
                buf.setFormat(format);
                buf.setFlags(buf.getFlags() | Buffer.FLAG_KEY_FRAME);
              }

              private void convertIntByteToByte(int[] src, int srcIndex, byte[] out, int outIndex) {
                // Note: the int[] returned by bufferedImage.getRaster().getPixels() is an int[]
                // where each int is the value for one color i.e. the first 4 ints contain the RGBA values for the first pixel
                int r = src[srcIndex];
                int g = src[srcIndex+1];
                int b = src[srcIndex+2];

                out[outIndex] = (byte) (r & 0xFF);
                out[outIndex+1] = (byte) (g & 0xFF);
                out[outIndex+2] = (byte) (b & 0xFF);
              }
              private byte[] convertTo24Bit(int[] input) {
                int dataLength = input.length;
                byte[] convertedData = new byte[ dataLength * 3 / 4 ];

                // for every 4 int values of the original array (RGBA) write 3
                // bytes (RGB) to the output array
                for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < dataLength; i+=4, j+=3) {
                  convertIntByteToByte(input, i, convertedData, j);
                }
                return convertedData;
              }

            }
}
```

I make the video using the following call in my main method

```
r.makeVideo("Video.mov");
```

And here is that method.

```
public void makeVideo (String movFile) throws MalformedURLException {

    JpegImagesToMovie imageToMovie = new JpegImagesToMovie();

    Vector<String> imgList = new Vector <String>();

    File f = new File("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\tmp\\");
    File[] fileList = f.listFiles();

    for (int i = 0; i < fileList.length; i++) {
        imgList.add(fileList[i].getAbsolutePath());
    }

    MediaLocator ml;

    if ((ml = imageToMovie.createMediaLocator(movFile)) == null) {
        System.exit(0);
    }

    imageToMovie.doIt(width, height, (1000/125), imgList, ml);

}
```

Error when running:

> Usage: java JpegImagesToMovie [-w ] [-h ] [-f ] [-o ] -i 
>   Since no input (-i) forder provided, assuming this JAR is inside JPEGs folder.
>   Usage: java JpegImagesToMovie [-w ] [-h ] [-f ] [-o ] -i 
>   Usage: java JpegImagesToMovie [-w ] [-h ] [-f ] [-o ] -i 
>   Trying to guess movie size from first image
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at maple.JpegImagesToMovie.main(JpegImagesToMovie.java:342)

line 342

```
width = firstImageInFolder.getWidth();
```

Comment: Like I said, I don't understand code snippets, please remove the original code, and put an SSCCE.  Oh I think I see what is going wrong..  will know more when I see that SSCCE.

Comment: I've added the latest full code.

Comment: If there is another way, instead of actually compressing it and getting the JpegToMovies.java to work with .png or another way to record video that would do.

Comment: Question:  Are you committed to a pure Java solution, or would it be possible to use Java to fire-off a third-party tool to do the converting?  Not sure what I'd recommend if third-party is an option, but I figure it'd open some possibilities, at least.

Comment: Ok so what is your error then? The video player cannot play the video? A message about the codec maybe? If yes, I have mentioned in my answer that not all players can play it. Try with Quicktime and let me know

Comment: Using the default Windows player doesn't work. Using VLC media player provides me with the error "No suitable decoder module:
VLC does not support the audio or video format "twos". Unfortunately there is no way for you to fix this." and when I run the file using Quicktime it's a distorted image that somewhat looks like my screen.

Comment: @user2612619 the error about the video format "twos" is what I also got with VLC. But Quicktime plays the video ok. Is it possible for you to upload the images somewhere so I can get them and test?

Comment: I've uploaded the images (located in the folder named "tmp") and the .mov file that was produced with those images. http://ge.tt/api/1/files/6ekvVMo/0/blob?download

Comment: The link does not work but I think I know what the problem might be: Your PNG files are probably not 32bit (i.e. they do not contain transparency). Can you please confirm if this is the case?

Comment: Sorry here is the working link. http://ge.tt/api/1/files/8L1eYMo/0/blob?download Also they the .png is a ss of my whole screen (using the Java robot).

Comment: My suspicion was correct. Your images are not 32-bit but 24-bit (i.e. no alpha layer). I have updated my answer with a new version of `PngImageSourceStream` that handles both cases. Replace the old code and you should be able to see your video in Quicktime now.

Comment: The new code produces and error, I've added it to the original post.

Comment: You don't have the images in the folder you are declaring as root i.e. if the code snippet above still stands, that would mean the folder `C:\Users\user\Desktop\tmp\` does not have any PNG files

Comment: Sorry I don't understand. The errors above are from the `JpegImagesToMovie` running. And especially its `main()` method i.e. you are not calling `doIt()` like in your other example. If you want to run the class stand alone, you need to provide at least the output folder as an argument with `-i C:\Users\user\Desktop\tmp`. If you are trying to invoke `main()` method from another program you need to pass those two values as arguments. And that folder should contain the PNG images. I am not sure what is not clear

Comment: Is there a better extension I can use that any OS can play without the aid of 3rd party software (ie Quicktime).

Comment: Ya, that was a mistake on my part.

Comment: @user2612619 I don't know. This has to do with the encoding of the video for which my knowledge is limited. I have just managed the image processing. Did you got the video right?

Comment: Yes, and thank you. I'll post another question I guess.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Though a little late (since the question is already answered), and because coincidentally I have worked with `ImageIO` in the past few days, I will just add here my answer. Especially the second part of how to make `JpegImagesToMovie` to work with png files has not been answered and it might help someone else.

**Double compression issue:** As correctly identified by others, you are effectively compressing the JPEG image twice by using `ImageIO.write()`. The `ImageIO` is a utility class that based on the type of the file ("jpeg" in our case) chooses an appropriate `ImageWriter`. It then constructs an `ImageInputStream` and it passes it to the writer. Last it calls its `write()` method. Pretty much what @meewoK does in his answer. However every `ImageWriter` can take a `ImageWriteParam` instance that configures its details. `ImageIO` apparently cannot know what parameters each writer can accept, nor how it should be configured, so default settings are used. If you look at the source `JPEGImageWriteParam` has a default quality factor of `0.75`, so you are *effectively multiplying* this factor with whatever quality used for the original file. (If it was 0.75 again, your final image has pretty much a `0.75 * 0.75 = 0.56` quality i.e. you lost the half of the original). Bottom line: Use `ImageIO` for quick reads or writes but if more control is desired the recommended approach is to configure and use an `ImageWriter` manually.

**How to make `JpegImagesToMovie` to work directly with PNG files:** If you look at the source of that class all the work is done in its `ImageSourceStream` inner class. What it does, is that it loads the bytes from the files (*each file is a video frame*) directly to a `Processor` class that creates the video. Conveniently the `Processor` knows how to handle JPEG format directly (look at the stream's constructor `format = new VideoFormat(VideoFormat.JPEG, ...)`), so feeding it with the raw file data works as expected.

To make it work with PNG format though, just replacing the file suffix as per your approach is not enough. You need to convert the PNG data to a format that `Processor` understands (i.e. to *decode* it). Below you can find a quick and dirty way to do that. **Disclaimer:** the approach below uses more memory since it loads the image in memory and it further manipulates it to convert it to a `byte[]`. So performance-wise and memory-wise is worst. However if memory and speed is not a concern, it would allow you to work directly with PNG files.

**Conversion steps:**

**a)** *With an editor* search and replace the string values `"jpeg", "jpg"` with `"png"`. The original author has those values hard-coded and during your attempt you have missed some entries.

**b)** In the constructor of the `ImageDataSource` replace the first line with the second one :

```
streams[0] = new ImageSourceStream(width, height, frameRate, images); // delete this line 
streams[0] = new PngImageSourceStream(width, height, frameRate, images); // add this line
```

**c)** At the end of the class add the implementation of the new `PngImageSourceStream` provided below.

You should now have a working copy of the original version that is able to read PNG files directly and convert them to a MOV video (Note: Not all players can play that new video because of the codec used. QuickTime and Media Player Classic worked ok for me)

**Update 1:** The original code of `PngImageSourceStream`assumed a 32-bit PNG file, a restriction I forgot to mention. The version below is a second version that supports either 32-bit or 24-bit (i.e. with no alpha layer) images.

```
class PngImageSourceStream extends ImageSourceStream {

  public PngImageSourceStream(int width, int height, int frameRate,
      Vector<String> images) {
    super(width, height, frameRate, images);

    // configure the new format as RGB format
    format = new RGBFormat(new Dimension(width, height),
        Format.NOT_SPECIFIED, Format.byteArray, frameRate, 
                                  24, // 24 bits per pixel
                                  1, 2, 3); // red, green and blue masks when data are in the form of byte[]
  }

  public void read(Buffer buf) throws IOException {

    // Check if we've finished all the frames.
    if (nextImage >= images.size()) {
      // We are done. Set EndOfMedia.
      System.err.println("Done reading all images.");
      buf.setEOM(true);
      buf.setOffset(0);
      buf.setLength(0);
      ended = true;
      return;
    }

    String imageFile = (String) images.elementAt(nextImage);
    nextImage++;

    System.err.println("  - reading image file: " + imageFile);

    // read the PNG image
    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File(imageFile));
    boolean hasAlpha = image.getColorModel().hasAlpha();
    Dimension size = format.getSize();

    // convert 32-bit RGBA to 24-bit RGB
    byte[] imageData = convertTo24Bit(hasAlpha, image.getRaster().getPixels(0, 0, size.width, size.height, (int[]) null));
    buf.setData(imageData);

    System.err.println("    read " + imageData.length + " bytes.");

    buf.setOffset(0);
    buf.setLength(imageData.length);
    buf.setFormat(format);
    buf.setFlags(buf.getFlags() | Buffer.FLAG_KEY_FRAME);
  }

  private void convertIntByteToByte(int[] src, int srcIndex, byte[] out, int outIndex) {
    // Note: the int[] returned by bufferedImage.getRaster().getPixels()
    // is an int[]
    // where each int is the value for one color i.e. the first 4 ints
    // contain the RGBA values for the first pixel
    int r = src[srcIndex];
    int g = src[srcIndex + 1];
    int b = src[srcIndex + 2];

    out[outIndex] = (byte) (r & 0xFF);
    out[outIndex + 1] = (byte) (g & 0xFF);
    out[outIndex + 2] = (byte) (b & 0xFF);
  }

  private byte[] convertTo24Bit(boolean hasAlpha, int[] input) {
    int dataLength = input.length;
    int newSize = (hasAlpha ? dataLength * 3 / 4 : dataLength);
    byte[] convertedData = new byte[newSize];

    // for every 4 int values of the original array (RGBA) write 3
    // bytes (RGB) to the output array
    // if there is no alpha (i.e. RGB image) then just convert int to byte
    for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < dataLength; i += 3, j += 3) {
      convertIntByteToByte(input, i, convertedData, j);
      if (hasAlpha) {
        i++; // skip an extra byte if the original image has an
            // extra int for transparency
      }
    }
    return convertedData;
  }

}
```

Comment: @AndrewThompson Thanks. ImageIO gave me a headache in the last few days :)

Comment: With time running out on the bounty, I've decided this is the most deserving answer since it better explains the 'why' of image saving.  Congrats!

Comment: @c.s. I've done everything you have said and I get the following error when I try to run the .mov file that is produced. I'll update the original post with the full SSCCE.

Comment: @user2612619 Copy-pasting the new version you have added in the question and running with its own `main()` from command line with parameters, works ok for me. Trying to run with your `makeVideo()` method results in an error `Cannot create the DataSink: javax.media.NoDataSinkException: `. Do you get the same error?

Comment: The makeVideo() provides me with no errors. I'll update the original post with the output in the console.

Comment: @user2612619 actually it runs fine with your method too (in my previous comment I have used a wrong url for the file). So please let me know 1) what error do you get and 2) the values for `String movFile` and `width, height` that you use when calling `makeVideo`

Comment: 1) There is no error when compiling/running. The .mov seems corrupt. 2) "Video.mov". 3) width = (int) Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().getWidth(); I use that for width and the same but .getHeight for the height. I have them as methods (setWidth() and setHeight()) and call them before calling the imageToMovie.doIt.

Comment: You need to use the width and height of your images, not the screen dimensions unless your images are full screenshots. If they are, then it is ok. However try if the movie plays with Quicktime as I suggested in my other comment

Comment: running your script above create blank video. When I tried play on Windows Media Player only black screen appears. When trying to run on VLC seems fine. Whats wrong? I add class `PngImageSourceStream ` and add `streams[0] = new PngImageSourceStream`. anything else?

Comment: I didn't mention your answer that told `(Note: Not all players can play that new video because of the codec used. QuickTime and Media Player Classic worked ok for me)`, thus is there any ways for me to run it on Windows Media Player? Can I convert it on FFMPEG?

Comment: Ive tried to Convert vcode x264 using FFMPEG but not work on Windows Media Player. I need to run that video on Windows Media Player.

Comment: @NPE you are commenting to a post that is 5 years old. As long as I remember my answer was about manipulating the image data so png files can be loaded. I haven't worked with video so I am not sure how to help you. Perhaps you should look into `javax.media` package or related resources on how to configure `Processor` and `ContentDescriptor` (I can see that the original example uses `FileTypeDescriptor.QUICKTIME` perhaps there are other parameters for different video formats)

Answer (score 5):

Set the JPEG compression level<sup>1</sup> to a higher quality.  This will result in a larger file size, but should fix the problem of quality.

But encode them only as:

```
ImageIO.write(img, "jpg", new File("..." + ".jpg"));
```

1. As seen in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5998015/418556) - screenshot below.

[image]

Compile and run the code in the linked answer, drag the `Slider` on the left up and down to see the result of that compression level in the JPEG (bottom/3rd image).  The text area at the bottom will show the size in bytes at that level of 'quality'.  The quality is inverse to the compression, and as you might notice from the images the JPEG at %80 quality is not only a bit 'murky', but is already significantly larger in bytes than the PNG.

Then have a careful look at the code, especially:

```
private Image getJpegCompressedImage(BufferedImage image) throws IOException {
    float qualityFloat = (float)quality.getValue()/100f;
    ByteArrayOutputStream outStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    ImageWriter imgWriter = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName( "jpg" ).next();
    ImageOutputStream ioStream = ImageIO.createImageOutputStream( outStream );
    imgWriter.setOutput( ioStream );

    JPEGImageWriteParam jpegParams = new JPEGImageWriteParam( Locale.getDefault() );
    jpegParams.setCompressionMode( ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT );
    jpegParams.setCompressionQuality( qualityFloat ); // Set the compression level

    imgWriter.write( null, new IIOImage( image, null, null ), jpegParams );

    ioStream.flush();
    ioStream.close();
    imgWriter.dispose();

    jpgSize = outStream.toByteArray().length;

    BufferedImage compressedImage = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(outStream.toByteArray()));
    return compressedImage;
}
```

Comment: How do I change the compression level?

Comment: I use that, but the image stays the same, both the quality and size. I'll update the original post with the code I'm using.

Comment: I've spotted a 'Java 101' error in your code.   But before we get to that, I want to know that you 1) Ran the code in the linked thread exactly as I posted it. 2) Dragged the slider button. 3) Saw a change in quality.

Comment: 1) Yes. 2) Yes. 3) Yes though I don't see much difference after 40+

Comment: OK good.  Thanks for confirming.  The reason I asked is because the code you posted calls `getJpegCompressedImage(img);` then immediately discards the JPEG compressed image, without either displaying it or saving it to disk.   Try **saving it** as quality 100, then produce the MOV.  It will be huge in bytes, but ignore that for the moment.  Report back whether the conversion to MOV produces a higher quality result.  Note that I do not mean try it with the quality beyond which you see no improvement (40), I do mean 100 explicitly.  Give JMF the ***best possible chance*** to make a quality MOV..

Comment: 1) I cannot read code in comments.  2) I am not good at understanding code snippets.  -- My recommendation is to [edit that info. into the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/17928719/edit), in the form of an SSCCE.  Let me know in a comment when that is done.

Comment: Edited the original post.

Answer (score 4):

I'm taking a stab at this by bypassing `ImgIO.write()` and directly writing the bytes to the file using a `FileOutputStream` ...

I'm bypasing `ImgIO.write` due to numerous mentions on the internet saying imagequality cannot be controlled through this method.

Quoting from here: http://www.universalwebservices.net/web-programming-resources/java/adjust-jpeg-image-compression-quality-when-saving-images-in-java

> If you've been using the imageIO.write method to save JPEG images, you may notice that some image lose quality. This is because you can't instruct the imagIO.write method to apply a certain compression quality to the images.

**My first Stab:**

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

public class Quality {

    public static void main (String[] args) {

        BufferedImage img;

        try {

            File f = new File("test" + ".jpg");
            img = ImageIO.read(f);
            writeJpegCompressedImage(img,"NEW" + ".jpg" );         

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }


    private static void writeJpegCompressedImage(BufferedImage image, String outFile) throws IOException {
        float qualityFloat = 1f;
        ByteArrayOutputStream outStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        ImageWriter imgWriter = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName( "jpg" ).next();
        ImageOutputStream ioStream = ImageIO.createImageOutputStream( outStream );
        imgWriter.setOutput( ioStream );

        JPEGImageWriteParam jpegParams = new JPEGImageWriteParam( Locale.getDefault() );
        jpegParams.setCompressionMode( ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT );
        jpegParams.setCompressionQuality( qualityFloat );

        imgWriter.write( null, new IIOImage( image, null, null ), jpegParams );

        ioStream.flush();
        ioStream.close();
        imgWriter.dispose();

        OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream ( outFile); 
        outStream.writeTo(outputStream);

    }
}
```

Comment: I thought the issue was that the images were not the same quality wise in previous code... saving with the previous code caused double JPEG encoding... Forgive me if I'm wrong, I took a stab at this. Additionally, I think Andrew said somewhere "It will be huge in bytes, but ignore that for the moment." Any clarifications regarding what you want to do are welcome. Also, you cannot create more quality than the original Jpeg image but I feel I may not be understanding everything...so clarifications are welcome.

Comment: This did help changing a .png to a compressed .jpg and the quality was better than the normal .jpg. Thank you. The reason I had confusion was because you had the line File f = new File("test" + ".jpg"); but it should be File f = new File("test" + ".png"); But thank you for this.

Comment: This would be accepted answer, `ImageIO.write` cannot control quality of image at all.